# Shift NaNs to the end of their respective rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a DataFrame like :

```
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  NaN  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN  2.0
```

---

What I want to get is

```
Out[116]: 
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

---

This is my approach as of now.

```
df.apply(lambda x : (x[x.notnull()].values.tolist()+x[x.isnull()].values.tolist()),1)
Out[117]: 
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

---

Is there any efficient way to achieve this ? `apply` Here is way to slow .
Thank you for your assistant!:)

---

My real data size

```
df.shape
Out[117]: (54812040, 1522)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that NaNs are located in contiguous cells?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sometime it will be 1 NaN 2 NaN

Comment: Aren't you shifting/pushing NaNs to the right rather for each row?

Comment: @Divakar Yes~ Make the notnull value to the left ~

Comment: This works better if I include a pd.Series, so I don't have to deal with lists:
.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x[x.notnull()].values.tolist()+x[x.isnull()].values.tolist()),1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a NumPy solution using [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/) -

```
In [455]: df
Out[455]: 
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  NaN  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN  2.0

In [456]: pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='left'))
Out[456]: 
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

If you want to save memory, assign it back instead -

```
df[:] = justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='left')
```

Comment: @Wen Would be nice to know the kind of timings you get on your dataset.

Comment: Your solution is faster than others, Thank you for your assistant!

Comment: @Wen Would have loved some kind of timing figures on your mentioned `(54812040, 1522)` dataset :) Though I am not sure how you are holding such a huge dataset!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think `sorted` holds a candle to numpy on 54 _**MILLION**_ data points.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yup, pandas apply is known for convenience from what little I know about it.

Comment: This is what I get: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: The original apply() method in the OP works though :)

Answer (score 5):

Your <s>best</s> easiest option is to use `sorted` on `df.apply/df.transform` and sort by nullity.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull), 1)
df
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

You may also pass `np.isnan` to the `key` argument.

Comment: I should make it more clear, some time it will be `1 NaN 2 NaN`, still a nice one !:)

Comment: @Wen Added another solution.

Comment: Dude, you kill it ! I was totally forgot `sorted keys` let me test it with my real data

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem to work with multi-index? It converts my dataframe into a series.