# Shifting Columns values towards left based on the value in them

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have business scenario, where I have an `id` column and `value` columns.
There are multiple `value` columns like value_1, value_2 etc.

The idea is to shift values of `value` column to left.

The Input is as below:

```
Input
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|          id|    value_1|  value_2|   value_3|  value_4|  value_5|  value_6|
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|           1|       1011|     1012|      1011|     2018|     null|     1011|
|           2|       null|     1012|      null|     2018|     null|     2022|
|           7|       1011|     1011|      1016|     2018|     null|     null|
|           8|       1011|     1012|      1014|     2018|     null|     null|
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The next step is to replace null values with actual by shifting the columns towards left. The idea is to all the valid valued columns should be kept to left and columns having `null` to be shfited right.
The intermedidate output looks as below:

```
Output1
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|          id|    value_1|  value_2|   value_3|  value_4|  value_5|  value_6|
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|           1|       1011|     1012|      1011|     2018|     1011|     null|
|           2|       1012|     2018|      2022|     null|     null|     null|
|           7|       1011|     1011|      1016|     2018|     null|     null|
|           8|       1011|     1012|      1014|     2018|     null|     null|
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Then, the duplicate values of rows must be removed and if possible the valid values must be shifted further left.
The sample output looks as below:

```
Output2
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|          id|    value_1|  value_2|   value_3|  value_4|  value_5|  value_6|
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|           1|       1011|     1012|      2018|     null|     null|     null|
|           2|       1012|     2018|      2022|     null|     null|     null|
|           7|       1011|     1016|      2018|     null|     null|     null|
|           8|       1011|     1012|      1014|     2018|     null|     null|
+------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Any leads on this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Code

```
cols = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3',
        'value_4', 'value_5', 'value_6']

arr = F.array_compact(F.array_distinct(F.array(*cols)))
df1 = df.select('id', *[arr[i].alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(cols)])
```

##### How this works

Create an array from the value columns then remove the duplicate values using `array_distinct` then use `array_compact` to drop the null values. Finally use a select expression to yank the cols from the resulting array and assign them back to the dataframe.

##### Result

```
df1.show()

+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|id |value_1|value_2|value_3|value_4|value_5|value_6|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|1  |1011   |1012   |2018   |null   |null   |null   |
|2  |1012   |2018   |2022   |null   |null   |null   |
|7  |1011   |1016   |2018   |null   |null   |null   |
|8  |1011   |1012   |1014   |2018   |null   |null   |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: hello @Shubham, Thanks for the solution. It reduces my existing code to 1/4. There is a challenge. I am using Spark version 3.1.  I think it does not support `array_compact `. Is there any alternative solution for spark 3.1

Comment: Can we use `array_remove` or `array_except` ?

Comment: The array_compact function is actually available in Spark versions >= 3.4. For older versions of Spark, you could use array_except.

Answer (score 1):

So this can be done in three steps:

##### Step 1: To get your 1st output we need to sort by [nullity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970751/shift-nans-to-the-end-of-their-respective-rows).

```
df = df.set_index('id').transform(lambda x: (sorted(x, key=pd.isnull)), 1)
```

##### Step 2: It is easier to take the transpose and then replace duplicates with NA

```
df_vals = df.T # (keeping this variable as a temp var, you can remove it)
import numpy as np
for col in df_vals.columns: 
    df_vals.loc[ df_vals.duplicated([col]), col] = np.nan
```

##### Step 3: need to resort by nullity to get your desired output:

```
# step 3 -> redo step 1 to sort by nans
df_vals.T.transform(lambda x: (sorted(x, key=pd.isnull)), 1)
```

Output:

```
|   id |   value_1 |   value_2 |   value_3 |   value_4 |   value_5 |   value_6 |
|-----:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|    1 |      1011 |      1012 |      2018 |       nan |       nan |       nan |
|    2 |      1012 |      2018 |      2022 |       nan |       nan |       nan |
|    7 |      1011 |      1016 |      2018 |       nan |       nan |       nan |
|    8 |      1011 |      1012 |      1014 |      2018 |       nan |       nan |
```