# Remove NaN values from pandas dataframe and reshape table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

- Given a dataframe with columns interspersed with `NaN`s, how can the dataframe be transformed to remove all the `NaN` from the columns?

### Sample DataFrames

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dataframe from list of lists
list_of_lists = [[ 4., 7., 1., np.nan],
                 [np.nan, np.nan, 3., 3.],
                 [ 4., 9., np.nan, np.nan],
                 [np.nan, np.nan, 7., 9.],
                 [np.nan, 2., np.nan, 2.],
                 [4., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]

df_from_lists = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

# dataframe from list of dicts
list_of_dicts = [{'A': 4.0, 'B': 7.0, 'C': 1.0},
                 {'C': 3.0, 'D': 3.0},
                 {'A': 4.0, 'B': 9.0},
                 {'C': 7.0, 'D': 9.0},
                 {'B': 2.0, 'D': 2.0},
                 {'A': 4.0}]

df_from_dicts = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

### Display of DataFrame

```py
     A    B    C    D
0  4.0  7.0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  3.0  3.0
2  4.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  7.0  9.0
4  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
5  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

### Expected Output

```py
     A    B    C    D
0  4.0  7.0  1.0  3.0
1  4.0  9.0  3.0  9.0
2  4.0  2.0  7.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need `apply` with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html), only is necessary create `numpy array` and reassign `Series` for reset indices:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,4],
                   'C':[7,np.nan,9,np.nan,2,np.nan],
                   'D':[1,3,np.nan,7,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'E':[np.nan,3,np.nan,9,2,np.nan]})

print (df)
     B    C    D    E
0  4.0  7.0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  3.0  3.0
2  4.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  7.0  9.0
4  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
5  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print (df1)
     B    C    D    E
0  4.0  7.0  1.0  3.0
1  4.0  9.0  3.0  9.0
2  4.0  2.0  7.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1** Here's one with array data -

```
a = df.values.T
df_out = pd.DataFrame(a[~np.isnan(a)].reshape(a.shape[0],-1).T)
```

Sample run -

```
In [450]: df
Out[450]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  9.0  7.0  8.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  5.0  7.0

In [451]: a = df.values.T

In [452]: pd.DataFrame(a[~np.isnan(a)].reshape(a.shape[0],-1).T)
Out[452]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  7.0  8.0
1  9.0  5.0  7.0
```

---

**Approach #2** As it turns out, we already have an utility for it : [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/) -

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  9.0  7.0  8.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  5.0  7.0

In [2]: pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=0, side='up')[:2])
Out[2]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  7.0  8.0
1  9.0  5.0  7.0
```

### Benchmarking

Approaches -

```
def app0(df): # @jezrael's soln
    return df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))

def app1(df): # Proposed in this post
    a = df.values.T
    return pd.DataFrame(a[~np.isnan(a)].reshape(a.shape[0],-1).T)

def app2(df): # Proposed in this post
    a = df.values
    return pd.DataFrame(justify(a, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=0, side='up')[:5])

def app3(df): # @piRSquared's soln-1
    v = df.values
    r = np.arange(v.shape[1])[None, :]
    a = np.isnan(v).argsort(0)
    return pd.DataFrame(v[a[:5], r], columns=df.columns)

def app4(df): # @piRSquared's soln-2
    return pd.DataFrame(
        (lambda a, s: a[~np.isnan(a)].reshape(-1, s, order='F'))
        (df.values.ravel('F'), df.shape[1]),
        columns=df.columns
    )
```

Timings -

```
In [513]: # Setup input dataframe with exactly 5 non-NaNs per col
     ...: m,n = 500,100
     ...: N = 5
     ...: a = np.full((m,n), np.nan)
     ...: row_idx = np.random.rand(m,n).argsort(0)[:N]
     ...: a[row_idx, np.arange(n)] = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,n))
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(a)
     ...: 

In [572]: %timeit app0(df)
     ...: %timeit app1(df)
     ...: %timeit app2(df)
     ...: %timeit app3(df)
     ...: %timeit app4(df)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 46.1 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 554 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 446 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 148 µs per loop
```

Comment: and `pd.DataFrame(df.unstack().dropna().values.T.reshape(df.shape[1], -1).T)`?

Answer (score 2):

Using @Divakar's sample dataframe

```
df

     0    1    2
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  9.0  7.0  8.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  5.0  7.0
```

---

```
v = df.values
r = np.arange(v.shape[1])[None, :]
a = np.isnan(v).argsort(0)

pd.DataFrame(v[a[:2], r], columns=df.columns)

     0    1    2
0  1.0  7.0  8.0
1  9.0  5.0  7.0
```

---

Inspired by @Divakar's answer

```
pd.DataFrame(
    (lambda a, s: a[~np.isnan(a)].reshape(-1, s, order='F'))(df.values.ravel('F'), df.shape[1]),
    columns=df.columns
)

     0    1    2
0  1.0  7.0  8.0
1  9.0  5.0  7.0
```