# Left justify string values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nan

So I have a DataFrame with 180000+ values and I need to (1) replace duplicate and certain values in cells by row and (2) rearrange. Here is my DataFrame, df:

```
    key   sellyr  brand  makrc  item1  item2  item3  item4  item5  item6
0   da12  2013    imp    apt    furi   apt    nan    nan    nan    nan
1   da32  2013    sa     rye    rye    app    nan    nan    nan    nan 
2   da14  2013    sa     pro    not    pro    pan    fan    nan    nan
........
```

nan values represent np.nan. And forbidden string is 'not'.

So what I need to do is check columns item1~6 replace strings that are contained in the makrc column with nan. As well, I also want to replace 'not's' with nan's. After replacing strings to np.nan, I need to rearrange the item1~6 to left justify non-nan data to the leftmost empty cell, as shown below, (expected output):

```
    key   sellyr  brand  makrc  item1  item2  item3  item4  item5  item6
0   da12  2013    imp    apt    furi   nan    nan    nan    nan    nan
1   da32  2013    sa     rye    app    nan    nan    nan    nan    nan 
2   da14  2013    sa     pro    pan    fan    nan    nan    nan    nan
........
```

So as you can see in a first index, I have removed apt string in item2 and changed to np.nan because same string is in makrc column. In index 1, I have removed rye and replace with np.nan. But this time, I rearranged the 'app' string from item2 to item1 because np.nan values should come after the values. In index 2, I have replaced pro and not since I need to replace every 'not'string in the item columns to np.nan. Also I have rearranged the items.

I've tried combining all item columns as a list and replacing it, but there are a few rows with only np.nan items. Can you guys recommend an ideal process to solve my problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, extract a slice of columns beginning with `item` -

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('item')
i = df.iloc[:, m]
```

Mask all values which meet your criteria. Use `isin` -

```
j = i[~i.isin(df.makrc.tolist() + ['not'])]
```

Now. sort values based on NaNs and assign back -

```
df.loc[:, m] = j.apply(sorted, key=pd.isnull, axis=1)
df

    key  sellyr brand makrc item1 item2  item3  item4  item5  item6
0  da12    2013   imp   apt  furi   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  da32    2013    sa   rye   app   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  da14    2013    sa   pro   pan   fan    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

---

**Details**

```
i

  item1 item2 item3 item4  item5  item6
0  furi   apt   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
1   rye   app   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
2   not   pro   pan   fan    NaN    NaN
```

```
j

  item1 item2 item3 item4  item5  item6
0  furi   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
1   NaN   app   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
2   NaN   NaN   pan   fan    NaN    NaN
```

---

**Toward Better Performance**

You could make use of a modified version of Divakar's [*`justified`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/4909087) function that works on object arrays -

```
def justify(a, invalid_val=0, axis=1, side='left'):    
    """
    Justifies a 2D array

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. It could be 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
        It should be 'left' or 'right' for axis=1 and 'up' or 'down' for axis=0.

    """

    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = pd.notnull(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    if (side=='up') | (side=='left'):
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val, dtype=object) 
    if axis==1:
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
    return out
```

```
df.loc[:, m] = justify(j.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='left')
df

    key  sellyr brand makrc item1 item2  item3  item4  item5  item6
0  da12    2013   imp   apt  furi   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  da32    2013    sa   rye   app   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  da14    2013    sa   pro   pan   fan    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

This should (hopefully) be faster than calling `apply`. You'll especially see speed gains using the original version of the function that is optimised for numeric data.