# Pandas: shifting columns in grouped dataframe if NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a grouped dataframe like so:

```
          │          product          │          category           
          │   spot1   spot2    spot3  │   spot1    spot2    spot3 
──────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────
 basket 1 │   NaN     apple    banana │    NaN     fruits   fruits
 basket 2 │   almond  carrot   NaN    │    nuts    veggies  NaN
```

One row represents a "basket" containing different food products (vegtables, fruits, nuts).

Each basket has 3 spots that can either contain a food product or not (=NaN).

**I would like the first column of group `product` to be as populated as possible.** That means if there is a NaN value in the first column of the product group and some value in the 2nd or n-th column if should shift to the left for each group.

Categories are related: in the example above a `baskets'` `spot1` of group `product` and `spot1` of group `category` belong together. Every data combination must have a value for product. If product is NaN then all the related items will be NaN as well.

The output should look something like:

```
          │          product          │          category           
          │   spot1   spot2    spot3  │   spot1    spot2    spot3 
──────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────
 basket 1 │   apple   banana   NaN    │    fruits   fruits   NaN  <-- this row shifted to left to "fill" first spot of product group
 basket 2 │   almond  carrot   NaN    │    nuts    veggies  NaN
```

---

jezrael's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304610/pandas-shifting-columns-depending-on-if-nan-or-not) was a good starting point for me:

```
#for each row remove NaNs and create new Series - rows in final df 
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
#if possible different number of columns like original df is necessary reindex
df1 = df1.reindex(columns=range(len(df.columns)))
#assign original columns names
df1.columns = df.columns
print (df1)
```

However, this solution ignores grouping. I only want values to shift left based on the specific group `product`.

---

### edit / minimal reproducible example

please use this code to get to the "starting point" of problem. The way I get to this point in my production code is more complex but this should do fine.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, 'NaN','NaN'], [1, 'apple','fruits'], [1,'banana', 'fruits'], [2, 'carrot','veggies'], [2, 'almond','nuts']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['basket','product', 'category'])
  
# print dataframe.
df

dfg = df.groupby(['basket', df.groupby(['basket']).cumcount() + 1]).first().unstack().reset_index()

print(dfg)
```

Comment: hello please add minimal reproductible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that would be helpful

Comment: @grymlin thanks for reaching out I added a MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trust there is an easier way to accomplish this, but the following should work.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make sure that `NaNs` are *actual* `NaNs`, e.g. not "NaN" (this is a string 
# like any other); or use `[1, None, None]`
data = [[1, np.nan,np.nan], 
        [1, 'apple','fruits'], 
        [1,'banana', 'fruits'], 
        [2, 'carrot','veggies'], 
        [2, 'almond','nuts']]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['basket','product', 'category'])
dfg = df.groupby(['basket', df.groupby(['basket']).cumcount() + 
                  1]).first().unstack().reset_index()

print(dfg)

  basket product                 category                
               1       2       3        1       2       3
0      1    None   apple  banana     None  fruits  fruits
1      2  carrot  almond     NaN  veggies    nuts     NaN
```

**Code**

```
dfg.set_index('basket',drop=True, inplace=True)
out = dfg.unstack().dropna()

out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    out.index.get_level_values(0),
    out.groupby(level=[2,0]).cumcount().add(1).to_numpy(),
    out.index.get_level_values(2)])

out = out.reset_index(drop=False).pivot(index='basket', 
                                        columns=['level_0','level_1'],
                                        values=0)\
    .reindex(dfg.columns, axis='columns').reset_index(drop=False)

print(out)

  basket product             category            
               1       2   3        1       2   3
0      1   apple  banana NaN   fruits  fruits NaN
1      2  carrot  almond NaN  veggies    nuts NaN
```

**Explanation**

- First, we use [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) to get a Series with a `MultiIndex` that consists of `col level 0`, `col level 1`, `index`. I.e.:

```
out = df.unstack().dropna()
print(out.head(4))

            basket
product  1  2         carrot
         2  1          apple
            2         almond
         3  1         banana
```

- Next, we use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on levels `0,2` (i.e. original `col level 0` and `basket`), and we use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get consecutive numbers for the items in each group (adding 1: `add(1)`. I.e. we are doing:

```
print(out.groupby(level=[2,0]).cumcount().add(1).to_numpy())

[1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2]
```

- We use this result inside [`pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) to overwrite the `MultiIndex` (specifically `level 1`) with a new index. I.e. we now have:

```
print(out.head(4))

            basket
product  1  2         carrot
            1          apple
         2  2         almond
            1         banana
```

- Now, finally, we can reset the index and use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to change the shape of `out` so that it matches the shape of the original `df`. Chaining [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) applied to the columns will both reset the order of the columns and add all the missing columns (e.g. `3` at `col level 1` for both values in `col level 0`, and they will be automatically filled with NaNs.

Comment: +1 for the explanations. your code works with your MRE, but if I use it on the one provided by me it results in all NaNs...

Comment: Edited the answer to make it work on your sample. Let me know if you still experience problems.

Comment: one more question @ouroboros1. It seems like your solution is tailored to my MRE with exactly 3 "spots". Lets say I have n possible spots per group, how could that be handled?

Comment: Adding more columns shouldn't matter. Do make sure that `level 1` of your columns contains *only* consecutive digits. Check: `print(dfg.columns.get_level_values(1))`. For this example: `Index(['', 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype='object')`. The first empty string is OK, that's `basket`, but all the other ones should be consecutive digits per main category in `col level 0` (i.e. `product`, `category`). I.e. what we are trying to do, is change `[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3]` (idx level 1 for `out`) into `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]`. So these last values should *always* be a subset of the previous set.