# Shifting multi-column data to the left Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to make whole columns data moved to left.
Only data should be shifted to the left 1 time and the columns should be fixed. 
Could you tell me how can I do this?

> Initial Data is :

```
              A1   A2   A3   A4   A5
     #0001    421  000  000  777  888
     #0002    382  403  430  320  055
     #0003    441  304  403  403  403
     #0004    430  403  206  N/A  312
     #0005    N/A  394  493  N/A  403
```

> Desire Data is :

```
              A1   A2   A3   A4   A5
     #0001    000  000  777  888  N/A
     #0002    403  430  320  055  N/A
     #0003    304  403  403  403  N/A
     #0004    403  206  N/A  312  N/A
     #0005    394  493  N/A  403  N/A
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47898659/4909087 works for numeric data, check the link.

Comment: @coldspeed Can you please write a comment on how to use `justify` to this scenario. To learn how it works before deleting my answer.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa If they are numbers, you can simply pass an array to [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/4909087): `v = df.values; v = justify(v); df.values[:] = v`

Comment: @coldspeed Checked isn't giving right results also the output array contains extreme values `-2147483648` in place of `np.nan`. Could you verify it?.

Comment: @coldspeed : that question is quite different. This question can be solved by much simpler answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple loop:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):  # loop till last but one column
    df.iloc[:,i] = df.iloc[:,i+1]   # each column gets values of next column

df[i+1] = np.nan                    # for last column;
```

Output:

```
        A1   A2     A3   A4  A5
#0001    0    0  777.0  888 NaN
#0002  403  430  320.0   55 NaN
#0003  304  403  403.0  403 NaN
#0004  403  206    NaN  312 NaN
#0005  394  493    NaN  403 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double transpose with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = df.T.shift(-1,axis=0).T

print(df)

          A1     A2     A3     A4  A5
#0001    0.0    0.0  777.0  888.0 NaN
#0002  403.0  430.0  320.0   55.0 NaN
#0003  304.0  403.0  403.0  403.0 NaN
#0004  403.0  206.0    NaN  312.0 NaN
#0005  394.0  493.0    NaN  403.0 NaN
```

Actually `df.shift(-1,axis=1)` should work but there is bug in the code:

```
print(df.shift(-1,axis=1))
          A1     A2     A3  A4  A5
#0001  777.0    0.0  888.0 NaN NaN
#0002  320.0  430.0   55.0 NaN NaN
#0003  403.0  403.0  403.0 NaN NaN
#0004    NaN  206.0  312.0 NaN NaN
#0005    NaN  493.0  403.0 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Simply `df.shift(-1, axis=1)` shifts on column.

Comment: @rushinstuffin It doesn't work, there is bug in shift code.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't realize that. It seems to be because of the NaN values? Without those it seems to work fine.