# consolidate duplicate columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a new dataframe (I set it the original dataframe as a blank DF) from a group of series.  This is the code I have to get the series.

```
all_keys = list(dict_months.keys())
for i in all_keys:
    for j in range(len(dict_months[i])):
        temp_num = df_mth_return.loc['1992-'+str(i),dict_months[i][j]]
        blank_df = blank_df.append(temp_num) # append Series to blank_df
```

Here is a sample output of the resulting series with each temp_num being a pandas Series

```
Date 
1992-02-03   -2.174845
Name: IBM US Equity, dtype: float64 
Date 
1992-02-03    0.878127
Name: MMM US Equity, dtype: float64
Date
1992-03-02   -3.884848
Name: IBM US Equity, dtype: float64
```

This is the result I get

```
en          IBM US Equity   MMM US Equity   IBM US Equity   MMM US Equity   IBM US Equity   IBM US Equity   
2/3/1992    -2.17485        0.878127          NaN          all the way across  >> NaN
3/2/1992        NaN             NaN         -3.88485          -2.47076       NaN    acorss >> 
1/2/1992        NaN             NaN            NaN               NaN         1.123077   NaN across >>>> 
7/1/1992        NaN             NaN            NaN               NaN               NaN  -3.19279    3.091772    NaN across >>>> 
4/1/1992  ETC.... DOWN
```

But I want the final dataframe to look like the following so that the columns that are the same are only shown once.  Can someone help out.  This is a small sample of the blank_DF, it goes on for multiple columns and many more rows.

```
           IBM US Equity    MMM US Equity
2/3/1992    -2.17485         0.878127
3/2/1992    -3.88485         -2.47076
1/2/1992    1.123077           NaN
7/1/1992    -3.19279         3.091772
4/1/1992      NaN             5.63469
5/1/1992    1.312976         2.867628
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `groupby` by columns and apply lambda function with `bfill` for back filling `NaN`s with `iloc` for select first column:

```
df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(lambda x: x.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
print (df)
          IBM US Equity  MMM US Equity
en                                    
2/3/1992      -2.174850       0.878127
3/2/1992      -3.884850      -2.470760
1/2/1992       1.123077            NaN
7/1/1992      -3.192790       3.091772
```

Another solution with `numpy` and  perfect Divakar function [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/2901002) - only select first values in 2d array by `[:, 0]`:

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series(justify(x.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='left')[:, 0])
df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(f)
print (df)
```

Comment: Nice, I guess this is what OP wanted.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thanks ;)