# Pandas Merge Rows with Duplicate Ids Conditionally, Suitable for to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have the following df and I want to merge the lines that have the same Ids, unless there are duplicates

```
Ids      A   B   C   D   E  F   G    H   I  J
4411    24  2   55  26  1                   
4411                        24  2   54  26  0
4412    22  4   54  26  0                   
4412                        18  8   54  26  0
7401    12  14  54  26  0                   
7401                        0   25  53  26  0
7402    24  2   54  26  0                   
7402                        25  1   54  26  0
10891   16  10  54  26  0                   
10891                       3   23  54  26  0
10891                       5   10  6   15  0
```

Example output

```
Ids      A   B   C   D   E  F   G    H   I  J
4411    24  2   55  26  1   24  2   54  26  0                               
4412    22  4   54  26  0   18  8   54  26  0                                   
7401    12  14  54  26  0   0   25  53  26  0                                   
7402    24  2   54  26  0   25  1   54  26  0                                   
10891   16  10  54  26  0   3   23  54  26  0               
10891                       5   10  6   15  0
```

I tried groupby but that throws errors when you write to csv.

Comment: How did you get that dataframe in the first place, may I ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses Divakar's [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/4909087) function. If needed, convert to numeric in advance:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
```

Now, call `groupby` + `transform`:

```
df.set_index('Ids')\
  .groupby(level=0)\
  .transform(
      justify, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=0, side='up'
  )\
  .dropna(how='all')

          A     B     C     D    E     F     G     H     I    J
Ids                                                            
4411   24.0   2.0  55.0  26.0  1.0  24.0   2.0  54.0  26.0  0.0
4412   22.0   4.0  54.0  26.0  0.0  18.0   8.0  54.0  26.0  0.0
7401   12.0  14.0  54.0  26.0  0.0   0.0  25.0  53.0  26.0  0.0
7402   24.0   2.0  54.0  26.0  0.0  25.0   1.0  54.0  26.0  0.0
10891  16.0  10.0  54.0  26.0  0.0   3.0  23.0  54.0  26.0  0.0
10891   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   5.0  10.0   6.0  15.0  0.0
```

Comment: Nice solution! +1

Comment: @Wen I remember, also that it performed much worse than Divakar's answer to the same question ;) Edit: Thanks Anton :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep. :-) But I still like your answer , easy to explain .:-)

Answer (score 2):

This should be slow , but can achieve what you need

```
df.replace('',np.nan).groupby('Ids').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x).apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull),0)).dropna(axis=0,thresh=2).fillna('')
Out[539]: 
     Ids     A     B     C     D    E     F     G     H     I    J
0   7402  24.0   2.0  54.0  26.0  0.0  25.0   1.0  54.0  26.0  0.0
2  10891  16.0  10.0  54.0  26.0  0.0   3.0  23.0  54.0  26.0  0.0
3  10891                                5.0  10.0   6.0  15.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the blank values are nan, another option using groupby and dropna:

```
df.loc[:,'A':'E'] = df.groupby('Ids').apply(lambda x: x.loc[:,'A':'E'].ffill(limit=1))
df.dropna(subset=['F','G','H','I','J'])
```