# Pandas: Remove all NaN values in all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a data frame with many null records:

```
Col_1    Col_2      Col_3
10         5          2
22         7          7
3         9          5       
4         NaN       NaN
5         NaN       NaN
6         4         NaN
7         6          7
8         10        NaN
12        NaN        1
```

I want to remove all NaN values in all rows of columns . As you could see, each column has different number of rows. So, I want to get something like this:

```
Col_1    Col_2      Col_3
10         5          2
22         7          7
3          9          5       
4          4          7
6          6          1
7         10          
8                 
12
```

I tried

```
filtered_df = df.dropna(how='any')
```

But it removes all records in the dataframe. How may I do that ?

Comment: But what would you want the remaining elements to be? DataFrames must have the same number of elements.

Comment: See the second part of my answer, but with "up" instead of "left"

Comment: @coldspeed I'm not really sure of your answer in the other question or its relevance to this one. DataFrames are for tabular data. If the data is a ragged matrix, it's probably not the right data structure.

Comment: @AmiTavory Fair enough, it may not be obvious how to go about things so I've reopened the question and answered it.

Comment: Done! Thank you for reminding @coldspeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you could see, each column has different number of rows.

A DataFrame is a tabular data structure: you can look up an index and a column, and find the value. If the number of rows is different per columns, then the index is meaningless and misleading. A `dict` might be a better alternative:

```
{c: df[c].dropna().values for c in df.columns}
```

or

```
{c: list(df[c]) for c in df.columns}
```

Comment: I completely 100% agree with every word here. I just think most housekeeping questions like this are spurred by display/representation for which I think questions like these are OK. Otherwise, it's recommended one cajoles the OP to uncover the X in the XY problem here... :)...

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `pd.concat` on a list of series.

Note that columns `Col_2` and `Col_3` are unavoidably `float` due to `NaN` elements, if you remove `dtype=object` as an option.

```
res = pd.concat([df[x].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for x in df], axis=1)

print(res)

   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
0     10    5.0    2.0
1     22    7.0    7.0
2      3    9.0    5.0
3      4    4.0    7.0
4      5    6.0    1.0
5      6   10.0    NaN
6      7    NaN    NaN
7      8    NaN    NaN
8     12    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Divakar's [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/4909087) function—

```
df[:] = justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=0, side='up')
df = df.fillna('')
```

```
print(df)

   Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
0   10.0     5     2
1   22.0     7     7
2    3.0     9     5
3    4.0     4     7
4    5.0     6     1
5    6.0    10      
6    7.0            
7    8.0            
8   12.0
```

Comment: The technical proficiency is impressive. Fundamentally, I less like it, for the reasons I outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one also

`censos_data.dropna(subset=censos_data.columns,inplace=True)`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting for formatting your answer