# How to flatten rows in df pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Many similar questions but none address my problem.

I have a df which looks like this:

```
             TikTok  Facebook  Instagram  YouTube  Snapchat  Twitter  Twitch
NET: Agree    0.66       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree    0.73       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree    0.64       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree    0.53       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree    0.68       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree    0.74       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree    0.52       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN      0.74        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN      0.63        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN      0.63        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN      0.64        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN      0.75        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN      0.68        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN      0.64        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN       0.68      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN       0.67      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN       0.68      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN       0.59      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN       0.71      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN       0.67      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN       0.57      NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN     0.79       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN     0.73       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN     0.73       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN     0.68       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN     0.81       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN     0.77       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN     0.70       NaN      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      0.53      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      0.67      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      0.46      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      0.42      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      0.59      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      0.58      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      0.45      NaN     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN     0.63     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN     0.62     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN     0.58     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN     0.60     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN     0.70     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN     0.65     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN     0.59     NaN
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN    0.66
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN    0.65
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN    0.60
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN    0.63
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN    0.69
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN    0.68
NET: Agree     NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN    0.55
```

Desired result:

```
          TikTok Facebook Instagram YouTube Snapchat Twitter Twitch
NET: Agree  0.66    0.74    0.68    0.79    0.53    0.63    0.66
NET: Agree  0.73    0.63    0.67    0.73    0.67    0.62    0.65
NET: Agree  0.64    0.63    0.68    0.73    0.46    0.58    0.6
NET: Agree  0.53    0.64    0.59    0.68    0.42    0.60    0.63
NET: Agree  0.68    0.75    0.71    0.81    0.59    0.70    0.69
NET: Agree  0.74    0.68    0.67    0.77    0.58    0.65    0.68
NET: Agree  0.52    0.64    0.57    0.70    0.45    0.59    0.55
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418202/pandas-remove-all-nan-values-in-all-columns

Comment: this worked - res = pd.concat([df[x].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for x in df], axis=1)