# Generate New DataFrame without NaN Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've the following Dataframe:

```
     a    b    c    d    e
0  NaN  2.0  NaN  4.0  5.0
1  NaN  2.0  3.0  NaN  5.0
2  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0  NaN
3  1.0  2.0  NaN  4.0  NaN
4  NaN  2.0  NaN  4.0  5.0
```

What I try to to is to generate a new Dataframe without the NaN values.
There are always the same number of NaN Values in a row.

The final Dataframe should look like this:

```
   x  y  z
0  2  4  5
1  2  3  5
2  1  3  4
3  1  2  4
4  2  4  5
```

Does someone know an easy way to do this?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using array indexing:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[df.notnull().values].reshape(df.shape[0],3),
             columns=list('xyz'),dtype=int)

    x   y   z
0   2   4   5
1   2   3   5
2   1   3   4
3   1   2   4
4   2   4   5
```

---

If the `dataframe` has more inconsistance values across rows like 1st row with 4 values and from 2nd row if it has 3 values, Then this will do:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   g
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 4.0 5.0 6.0
1   NaN 2.0 3.0 NaN 5.0 NaN
2   1.0 NaN 3.0 4.0 NaN NaN
3   1.0 2.0 NaN 4.0 NaN NaN
4   NaN 2.0 NaN 4.0 5.0 NaN

pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: x.values[x.notnull()],axis=1).tolist())

    0   1   2   3
0   2.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
1   2.0 3.0 5.0 NaN
2   1.0 3.0 4.0 NaN
3   1.0 2.0 4.0 NaN
4   2.0 4.0 5.0 NaN
```

Here we cannot remove `NaN's` in last column.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180) function and select first 3 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values,invalid_val=np.nan)[:, :3].astype(int),
                  columns=list('xyz'), 
                  index=df.index)
print (df)
   x  y  z
0  2  4  5
1  2  3  5
2  1  3  4
3  1  2  4
4  2  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your example, values increase across columns, you can sort over `axis=1`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, 1)[:, :3],
                   columns=list('xyz'), dtype=int)

print(res)

   x  y  z
0  2  4  5
1  2  3  5
2  1  3  4
3  1  2  4
4  2  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use panda's method for dataframe [`df.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

This method is used for converting the NaN or NA to your given parameter.

> df.fillna(param to replace Nan)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
    data = {
         'A':[np.nan,  2.0,  np.nan,  4.0,  5.0],
         'B':[np.nan,  2.0,  3.0,  np.nan,  5.0],
         'C':[1.0 , np.nan,  3.0,  4.0,  np.nan],
         'D':[1.0 , 2.0,  np.nan,  4.0,  np.nan,],
         'E':[np.nan,  2.0,  np.nan,  4.0,  5.0]
        }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)

    
         A    B    C    D    E
    0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
    1  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0
    2  NaN  3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
    3  4.0  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0
    4  5.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
    
    df = df.fillna(0) # Applying the method with parameter 0
    print(df)

         A    B    C    D    E
    0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
    1  2.0  2.0  0.0  2.0  2.0
    2  0.0  3.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
    3  4.0  0.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
    4  5.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  5.0
```

If you want to apply this method to the particular column, the syntax would be like this

> df[column_name] = df[column_name].fillna(param)

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(0)
print(df)

     A    B    C    D    E
0  0.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0
2  0.0  3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
3  4.0  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
```

You can also use Python's `replace()` method to replace `np.nan`

```
df = df.replace(np.nan,0)
print(df)

 A    B    C    D    E
0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  2.0  2.0  0.0  2.0  2.0
2  0.0  3.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
3  4.0  0.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  5.0

df['A'] = df['A'].replace() # Replacing only column A

print(df)

A    B    C    D    E
0  0.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  2.0
2  0.0  3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
3  4.0  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
```