# Step left rows values until not null in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

I have to handle a huge amount of data. Every row starts with 1 or 0. I need a dataframe where every rows start with 1, so I have to step left all rows values till the first value is 1.

For example:

```
0 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

The result has to be this:

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I don't want to use for, while, etc., because I need some faster methods with pandas or numpy.

Do you have idea for this problem?

Comment: are you doing circular shift or filling with `0`?

Comment: @pault want to flag as dupe? Just noticed my solution is basically the accepted answer there.

Comment: @user3483203 I don't know- it depends on if the desired shift is circular, no?

Comment: @pault the shift being circular should never matter, because you will always stop when a 1 is in index 0, which means that a 1 will never wrap around.  Either way, the other answer doesn't talk about how to determine the offset, so I think it's fine to leave this open

Answer (score 4):

You may using with `cummax` to mask all position need to shift as `NaN` and `sorted`

```
df[df.cummax(1).ne(0)].apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[310]: 
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1
2  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
3  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Or we using the function [justify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180) write by ***Divakar***(much faster than the apply sorted)

```
pd.DataFrame(justify(df[df.cummax(1).ne(0)].values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='left')).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[314]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1
2  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
3  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Man, Divakar is a numpy god, damn

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`numpy.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) here:

```
a = df.values
s = a.argmax(1) * - 1
m, n = a.shape
r, c = np.ogrid[:m, :n]
s[s < 0] += n
c = c - s[:, None]
a[r, c]
```

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

---

***Timings***

```
In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 1000)))

In [36]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(justify(df[df.cummax(1).ne(0)].values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='left')).fillna(0).a
    ...: stype(int)
116 ms ± 640 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [37]: %%timeit
    ...: a = df.values
    ...: s = a.argmax(1) * - 1
    ...: m, n = a.shape
    ...: r, c = np.ogrid[:m, :n]
    ...: s[s < 0] += n
    ...: c = c - s[:, None]
    ...: pd.DataFrame(a[r, c])
    ...:
    ...:
11.3 ms ± 18.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

For performance, you can use `numba`. An elementary loop, but effective given JIT-compilation and use of more basic objects at C-level:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def shifter(A):
    res = np.zeros(A.shape)
    for i in range(res.shape[0]):
        start, end = 0, 0
        for j in range(res.shape[1]):
            if A[i, j] != 0:
                start = j
                break
        res[i, :res.shape[1]-start] = A[i, start:]
    return res
```

**Performance benchmarking**

```
def jpp(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(shifter(df.values).astype(int))

def user348(df):
    a = df.values
    s = a.argmax(1) * - 1
    m, n = a.shape
    r, c = np.ogrid[:m, :n]
    s[s < 0] += n
    c = c - s[:, None]
    return pd.DataFrame(a[r, c])    

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 1000)))

assert np.array_equal(jpp(df).values, user348(df).values)

%timeit jpp(df)      # 9.2 ms per loop
%timeit user348(df)  # 18.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `stride_tricks` solution, which is fast because it enables slice-wise copying.

```
def pp(x):
    n, m = x.shape
    am = x.argmax(-1)
    mam = am.max()
    xx = np.empty((n, m + mam), x.dtype)
    xx[:, :m] = x
    xx[:, m:] = 0
    xx = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(xx, (n, mam+1, m), (*xx.strides, xx.strides[-1]))
    return xx[np.arange(x.shape[0]), am]
```

It pads the input with the required number of zeros and then creates a sliding window view using `as_strided`. This is addressed using fancy indexing, but necause the last dimension is not indexed copying of lines is optimized and fast.

How fast? For large enough inputs on par with numba:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10000, 10))

from timeit import timeit

shifter(x) # that should compile it, right?

print(timeit(lambda:shifter(x).astype(x.dtype), number=1000))
print(timeit(lambda:pp(x), number=1000))
```

Sample output:

```
0.8630472810036736
0.7336142909916816
```

Comment: Yep, I see this small +/- versus `numba` for different shapes. I need to learn `np.lib.stride_tricks`, though am slightly put off by the disclaimer in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html).

Comment: @jpp the sliding window view also exists as a ready-made function in `skimage.util`, which reduces the danger of shooting ones foot.