# How to calculate the average of the most recent three non-nan value using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe `df` looks like the following. I want to calculate the average of the last 3 non nan columns. If there are less than three non-missing columns then the average number is missing.

```
name day1 day2 day3 day4  day5 day6 day7
A    1     1   nan   2    3    0   3
B    nan   nan nan   nan  nan  nan 3
C    1     1   0     1    1    1   1
D    1     1   0     1    nan  1   4
```

The expect output should looks like the following

```
name day1 day2 day3 day4  day5 day6 day7    expected 
A    1     1   nan   2    3    0   3        2     <-  1/3*(day5 + day6 + day7)
B    nan   nan nan   nan  nan  nan 3        nan   <-  less than 3 non-missing
C    1     1   0     1    1    1   1        1     <-  1/3*(day5 + day6 + day7)
D    1     1   0     1    nan  1   4        2    <-  1/3 *(day4 + day6 + day7)
```

I know how to calculate the average of the last three column and count how many non-missing observation are there. 
`df.iloc[:, 5:7].count(axis=1) average of the last three column`
`df.iloc[:, 5:7].count(axis=1) number of non-nan in the last three column`

If there are less than 3 non-missing observation, I know how to set the average value to missing using  `df.iloc[:, 1:7].count(axis=1) <= 3`.

But I am struggling to find a way to calculate the average of the last three non-missing columns. Can anyone teach me how to solve this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vectorized one using [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/) -

```
N = 3 # last N entries for averaging
avg = np.mean(justify(df.values,invalid_val=np.nan,axis=1, side='right')[:,-N:],1)
df['expected'] = avg
```

Comment: I know I will see `justify` here :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a custom function. This is only partially vectorised.

```
def mean_calculator(row):
    non_nulls = row.notnull()
    if non_nulls.sum() < 3:
        return np.nan
    return row[non_nulls].values[-3:].mean()

df['expected'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(mean_calculator, axis=1)

print(df)

  name  day1  day2  day3  day4  day5  day6  day7  expected
0    A   1.0   1.0   NaN   2.0   3.0   0.0     3       2.0
1    B   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     3       NaN
2    C   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0     1       1.0
3    D   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   NaN   1.0     4       2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by calculating the `expected` column using applying the following function:

```
expected = df.apply(lambda x: x[~x.isnull()][-3:].mean(), axis = 1)
```

And insert these values in the columns that have at least `3` valid values:

```
m = df.isnull().sum(axis=1) > 3
df.loc[~m,'expected'] = expected.mask(m)

       day1  day2  day3  day4  day5  day6  day7  expected
name                                                    
A      1.0   1.0   NaN   2.0   3.0   0.0     3       2.0
B      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     3       NaN
C      1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0     1       1.0
D      1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   NaN   1.0     4       2.0
```