# How do I get first non Other on multiple column label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset, call them `df`

```
Id  Name   Math    Physics   Biology   Chemistry
1   Andy   A       B         A         B
2   Bert   Other   C         Other     A
3   Candy  Other   Other     A         B
4   Dony   B       A         C         B
```

The expected value excludes `'Other'`, first expected value is called as `'Grade'`:

```
Id  Name   Math    Physics   Biology   Chemistry  Grade
1   Andy   A       B         A         B          A   
2   Bert   Other   C         Other     A          C
3   Candy  Other   Other     A         B          A
4   Dony   B       A         C         B          B
```

Comment: What have to try so far which doesn't work? Can you list down at least 1 of your approach?

Comment: if you replace other by np.nan , then `df['Grade']=df.iloc[:,2:].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)

You can mask by a Boolean dataframe, then backfill and take the first column:

```
df['Grade'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].mask(df.iloc[:, 2:].eq('Other')).bfill(1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Comment: Nice one with the mask.eq , would have implemented if known. :) +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/9698684):

```
df['Grade'] = justify(df.iloc[:,2:].values, invalid_val='Other')[:,0]

    Id   Name   Math Physics Biology Chemistry Grade
0   1   Andy      A       B       A         B     A
1   2   Bert  Other       C   Other         A     C
2   3  Candy  Other   Other       A         B     A
3   4   Dony      B       A       C         B     B
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) + [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['Grade'] = df.lookup(df.index, (df.iloc[:, 2:] != 'Other').idxmax(axis=1))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Id   Name   Math Physics Biology Chemistry Grade
0   1   Andy      A       B       A         B     A
1   2   Bert  Other       C   Other         A     C
2   3  Candy  Other   Other       A         B     A
3   4   Dony      B       A       C         B     B
```

With `idxmax` you get for each row the first column index that is different than `Other`. Then use `lookup` to get the values at each cell.

Answer (score 1):

replace `'Other'` by `np.nan`

```
>>df.replace('Other',np.nan,inplace=True)
```

Then :

```
>>df['Grade']=df.iloc[:,2:].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
```

Restore the `Other` in place of `np.nan`

```
>>df.replace(np.nan,'Other',inplace=True)
```