# Convert upper triangular matrix to lower triangular matrix in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried using transpose and adding some twists to it but it didn't workout

Convert Upper:

```
 Data : 
     0         1         2      3  
0  5         NaN       NaN      NaN
1  1         NaN       NaN      NaN
2  0.21      0.31      0.41     0.51   
3  0.32      0.42      0.52     NaN
4  0.43      0.53      NaN      NaN
5  0.54      NaN       NaN      Nan
```

to:

```
 Data : 
     0         1         2      3  
0  5         NaN       NaN      NaN
1  1         NaN       NaN      NaN
2  0.21      NaN       NaN      NaN   
3  0.31      0.32      NaN      NaN
4  0.41      0.42      0.43     NaN
5  0.51      0.52      0.53     0.54
```

without effecting the first two rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180) with [`sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with exclude first 2 rows:

```
arr = justify(df.values[2:,:], invalid_val=np.nan, side='down', axis=0)
df.values[2:,:] = np.sort(arr, axis=1)

print (df)
      0     1     2     3
0  5.00   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  1.00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  0.21   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  0.31  0.32   NaN   NaN
4  0.41  0.42  0.43   NaN
5  0.51  0.52  0.53  0.54
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it vice versa too?

Comment: @Rookie - Try `df.values[2:,:] = justify(df.values[2:,:].T, invalid_val=np.nan, side='left', axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can first index the dataframe from row `2` onwards and swap with the transpose, and then you can use [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/9698684) so that all `NaNs` are at the top:

```
df.iloc[2:,:] = df.iloc[2:,:].T.values
pd.Dataframe(justify(df.values.astype(float), invalid_val=np.nan, side='down', axis=0))

   0         1         2      3  
0  5         NaN       NaN      NaN
1  1         NaN       NaN      NaN
2  0.21      NaN       NaN      NaN   
3  0.31      0.32      NaN      NaN
4  0.41      0.42      0.43     NaN
5  0.51      0.52      0.53     0.54
```