# Remove NaNs from Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, null

I have the following code:

```
sample_data = OrderedDict((df.name, df['col'].sample(n=3)) for df in test_cases[1:])
sample = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
```

Which gives the following dataframe:

```
col1   col2
A      NaN
P      NaN
NaN    E
NaN    R
U      NaN
NaN    Y
```

How do I get the following dataframe:

```
 col1   col2
 A      E
 P      R
 U      Y
```

Comment: What happens if you have unequal number of not null values per column?

Comment: @Vaishali I should always have the same number of populated values per column due to the sample that is taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution is to use *[dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)*, *[reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)* and *[concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)*.

```
pd.concat([df[x].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for x in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
li=[['A',np.nan],['P',np.nan],[np.nan,'E'],[np.nan,'R'],['U',np.nan],[np.nan,'Y']]
df=pd.DataFrame(li,columns=['col1','col2'])
df2=pd.concat([df[x].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for x in df.columns], axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Output

```
  col1 col2
0    A    E
1    P    R
2    U    Y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension to find the not null values and reconstruct the dataframe,

```
pd.DataFrame([df.loc[df[col].notna(), col].values for col in df.columns]).T


    0   1
0   A   E
1   P   R
2   U   Y
```

Or

```
a = np.array([df.loc[df[col].notna(), col].values for col in df.columns]).T

pd.DataFrame(a, columns = df.columns)

    col1    col2
0   A       E
1   P       R
2   U       Y
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna()
Out[485]: 
  col1 col2
0    A    E
1    P    R
2    U    Y
```

If the performance is matter check [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180)