# Selective Pandas dropna so that the DataFrame will be different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to drop the `nan` values in my DataFrame `df`, however I am having difficulty in dropping the for each column without effecting the entire row. An example of my `df` can be seen below.

```
Advertising No Advertising
nan          7.0
71.0         nan
65.0         nan
14.0         nan
76.0         nan
nan          36.0
nan          9.0
73.0         nan
85.0         nan
17.0         nan
nan          103.0
```

My desired output is shown below.

```
Advertising No Advertising
71.0        7.0
65.0        36.0 
14.0        9.0
76.0        103.0 
73.0         
85.0                     
17.0
```

The examples given are just a snippet of the total DataFrame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [justify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/2901002) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=0, side='up'), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns).dropna(how='all')
print (df)
    Advertising  No Advertising
0          71.0             7.0
1          65.0            36.0
2          14.0             9.0
3          76.0           103.0
4          73.0             NaN
5          85.0             NaN
6          17.0             NaN
```

Another slowier solution is use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print (df)

   Advertising  No Advertising
0         71.0             7.0
1         65.0            36.0
2         14.0             9.0
3         76.0           103.0
4         73.0             NaN
5         85.0             NaN
6         17.0             NaN
```

Mixing numeric with strings (empty strings) is not good idea, because if need processes number later pandas functions failed, so rather dont do it.

But is is possible by :

```
df = df.fillna('')
```