# numpy python raising non zero values to top of 2d array quickly and efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Sorry about the title, I would be looking for a suggestion if someone has a better description.  I want a function (that is as quick as possible) that gets the non-zero entries and populates a new array with the ordered version of the previous array.  It probably is clearer from the example below:

**Input Array**

```
np.random.seed(2)
a = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
b = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
c = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
a = 0 * (a % 2) + (1-(a % 2))*a
b = 0 * (b % 2) + (1-(b % 2))*b
c = 0 * (c % 2) + (1-(c % 2))*c
arr = np.array([a,b,c])

arr
>>> array([[8, 8, 6, 2, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4],
           [4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 0, 0, 6, 0],
           [0, 0, 8, 4, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4]])
```

**Output Array**

```
outArr = np.empty_like(arr)
outArr[0,:] = (arr[0,:] > 0) * arr[0,:] + ~(arr[0,:] > 0) * (arr[1,:] > 0) * arr[1,:] + ~(arr[0,:] > 0) * ~(arr[1,:] > 0) * arr[2,:]
outArr[1,:] = (arr[0,:] > 0) * arr[1,:] + (arr[0,:] > 0) * ~(arr[1,:] > 0) * arr[2,:]
outArr[2,:] = (arr[0,:] > 0) * (arr[1,:] > 0) * arr[2,:]

outArr
>>> array([[8, 8, 6, 2, 8, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4],
           [4, 0, 8, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Where I have hard coded this array to be 3 rows only so I can hand type the function, in reality this could be more rows (on the order of tens nothing too crazy).

*EDIT:*

The dimensions that I would actually like to use are 5ish rows by 100-150k columns

The data type will always be integers

Finally, the update process is I add a new row at the bottom, justify upwards, and then remove all trailing rows of only 0s (null values)

Comment: Can you add the actual input information into the question? Considering the particular shape, there could be better ways.

Comment: @Divakar added info, please let me know if that's sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Inspired by [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/), here's one fine-tuned for `up-justification` and for cases when sorting could slow things down, so an alternative one with `broadcasted-mask-creation` could be suggested -

```
def justify_up(a, invalid_val=0, use_sort=True):
    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val

    if use_sort==1:
        justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=0)[::-1]
    else:
        justified_mask = (mask.sum(0) > np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None])

    if invalid_val is 0:
        out = np.zeros_like(a)
    elif invalid_val is 1:
        out = np.ones_like(a)
    else:
        out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val)

    out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [199]: arr
Out[199]: 
array([[8, 8, 6, 2, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 0, 0, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 8, 4, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4]])

In [200]: justify_up(arr, invalid_val=0)
Out[200]: 
array([[8, 8, 6, 2, 8, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4],
       [4, 0, 8, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Approach #2**

We can also offload the work with loops to `numba` for performance for `in-situ` edit -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def justify_up_numba(a, invalid_val=0):
    # invalid_val : Any number but NaN
    m,n = a.shape
    for j in range(m-1):
        for i in range(0,m-j-1):
            for k in range(n):
                if a[i,k]==invalid_val:
                    a[i,k] = a[i+1,k]
                    a[i+1,k] = invalid_val      
    return a
```

Timings on large array -

```
In [361]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: arr = np.random.randint(0,5,(10,100000))

In [362]: %timeit justify_up(arr, invalid_val=0, use_sort=False)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

In [363]: %timeit justify_up(arr, invalid_val=0, use_sort=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.9 ms per loop

In [364]: %timeit justify_up_numba(arr, invalid_val=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop
```

Comment: Darn you crushed those runtimes, I will have to read more about numba. Thank you alot!