# how to collapse columns in pandas on null values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, concatenation

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':    ["a", "a", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
            'override1': ["b", np.nan, "b", np.nan, np.nan],
            'override2': ["c", np.nan, np.nan, "c", np.nan]})


    col1    override1   override2
0     a        b          c
1     a       NaN        NaN
2     NaN      b         NaN
3     NaN     NaN         c
4     NaN     NaN         NaN
```

Is there a way to collapse the 3 columns into one column, where `override2` overrides `override1`, which overrides `col1`,  however, in case there is NaN, then the values bofore is to be kept? Also, I am mainly looking for a way where I would not have to make an additional column. I am really looking for a built-in pandas solution.

This is the output I am looking for:

```
 collapsed
0  c
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  NaN
```

Comment: `df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `ffill`

```
df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
```

Comment: @Divakar aha , thank you sir , in term of performance I will still recommend justify

Comment: interestingly enough, this method is not even documented https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward solution involves forward filling and picking off the last column. This was mentioned in the comments.

```
df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1].to_frame(name='collapsed')

  collapsed
0         c
1         a
2         b
3         c
4       NaN
```

---

If you're interested in performance, we can use a modified version of Divakar's justify function:

```
pd.DataFrame({'collapsed': justify(
    df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='right')[:,-1]
})

  collapsed
0         c
1         a
2         b
3         c
4       NaN
```

[Reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/4909087)

> ```
> def justify(a, invalid_val=0, axis=1, side='left'):    
>     """
>     Justifies a 2D array
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     A : ndarray
>         Input array to be justified
>     axis : int
>         Axis along which justification is to be made
>     side : str
>         Direction of justification. It could be 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
>         It should be 'left' or 'right' for axis=1 and 'up' or 'down' for axis=0.
>
>     """
>
>     if invalid_val is np.nan:
>         mask = pd.notna(a)   # modified for strings
>     else:
>         mask = a!=invalid_val
>     justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
>     if (side=='up') | (side=='left'):
>         justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
>     out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val, dtype=a.dtype) 
>     if axis==1:
>         out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
>     else:
>         out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
>     return out
> ```

Comment: @WeNYoBen Just thought I'd throw a good solution into the mix (also, free advertising for Divakar :-D)

Answer (score 4):

Performance **NOT** in mind but rather beauty and elegance (-:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).last().reindex(df.index)

0      c
1      a
2      b
3      c
4    NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```
df.lookup(df.index , df.notna().cumsum(1).idxmax(1))
# array(['c', 'a', 'b', 'c', nan], dtype=object)
```

---

Or equivalently working with the underlying `numpy` arrays, and changing [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with [`ndarray.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html):

```
df.values[df.index, df.notna().cumsum(1).values.argmax(1)]
# array(['c', 'a', 'b', 'c', nan], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3):

With focus on performance, here's one with NumPy -

```
In [106]: idx = df.shape[1] - 1 - df.notnull().to_numpy()[:,::-1].argmax(1)

In [107]: pd.Series(df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)),idx])
Out[107]: 
0      c
1      a
2      b
3      c
4    NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':    ["a", "a", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
            'override1': ["b", np.nan, "b", np.nan, np.nan],
            'override2': ["c", np.nan, np.nan, "c", np.nan]})

print(df)
df=df['col1'].fillna('') + df['override1'].fillna('')+ df['override2'].fillna('')
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I will add str[:-1] at the end