# How to rightly extract data from some different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to extract data from some columns and merge it to new column. I have pandas dataframe :

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 
 A    No   No   No
 A    No   No   No
 A    No   No   No
 No   No   No   D
 No   B    No   No
 No   No   C    No
 No   No   C    No
```

I want to get new column like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 targetCol
 A    No   No   No     A
 A    No   No   No     A
 A    No   No   No     A
 No   No   No   D      D
 No   B    No   No     B
 No   No   C    No     C
 No   No   C    No     C
```

I tried to use lambda and simple condition, but it doesn't work. Some code which didn't work:

```
df['targetCol'] = df['A'] if df_razm['A'] != 'No' else None
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replace` with `max` over `axis=1`

```
df['targetCol'] = df.replace('No', '').max(axis=1)

  col1 col2 col3 col4 targetCol
0    A   No   No   No         A
1    A   No   No   No         A
2    A   No   No   No         A
3   No   No   No    D         D
4   No    B   No   No         B
5   No   No    C   No         C
6   No   No    C   No         C
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
df['targetCol'] = df.values[df.index, df.ne('No').values.argmax(1)]

   col1 col2 col3 col4 targetCol
0    A   No   No   No         A
1    A   No   No   No         A
2    A   No   No   No         A
3   No   No   No    D         D
4   No    B   No   No         B
5   No   No    C   No         C
6   No   No    C   No         C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [justify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180):

```
df=df.assign(target=justify(df.values,invalid_val='No')[:,0])
```

---

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 target
0    A   No   No   No      A
1    A   No   No   No      A
2    A   No   No   No      A
3   No   No   No    D      D
4   No    B   No   No      B
5   No   No    C   No      C
6   No   No    C   No      C
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['targetCol'] = df.replace("No", np.NaN).apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) with a custom function :

```
def extract_value(x,invalid_value):
    return x[x!=invalid_value].values[0]

df["target_column"]=df.apply(func=extract_value,axis=1,invalid_value="No")
```