# How to remove missing data and 0s whilst keeping the dataframe the same shape using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, reformat

I have a dataframe and I want to reformat it in order it remove the instances of whether a missing value or a zero occurs before the first non-zero value appears across a row. However I do not want to delete any rows or columns and I do not want to remove any 0s or missing values which appear after the non-zeroes.

Below is the dataframe I am working with:

```
> data =[['Adam',2.55,4.53,3.45,2.12,3.14],['Bill',np.NaN,2.14,3.65,4.12],['Chris',np.NaN,0,2.82,0,6.04],['David',np.NaN,0,7.42,3.52]]

> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'A','B','C','D','E'])
```

Moreover, here is the expected outcome:

```
> data1 =[['Adam',2.55,4.53,3.45,2.12,3.14],['Bill',2.14,3.65,4.12],['Chris',2.82,0,6.04],['David',7.42,3.52]]

> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Name', 'A','B','C','D','E'])
```

Comment: That's a strange task you've got here. So you don't care that the column's values will shift?

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont want to remove any rows or columns". Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: I want the values to shift so that every person starts off at the same time with a non-zero value. And in regards to "I dont want to remove any rows or columns" I want to keep the overall table the same shape. Sorry if I did not make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem. Here is the solution:

```
m=df.set_index('Name')
m=m[m.isin(m.mask(m.le(0)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]).cumsum(axis=1).astype(bool)]
print(m)
```

---

```
         A     B     C     D     E
Name                               
Adam   2.55  4.53  3.45  2.12  3.14
Bill    NaN  2.14  3.65  4.12   NaN
Chris   NaN   NaN  2.82  0.00  6.04
David   NaN   NaN  7.42  3.52   NaN
```

Then using [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180):

```
pd.DataFrame(justify(m.values,np.nan),columns=m.columns,index=m.index).reset_index()
```

---

```
    Name     A     B     C     D     E
0   Adam  2.55  4.53  3.45  2.12  3.14
1   Bill  2.14  3.65  4.12   NaN   NaN
2  Chris  2.82  0.00  6.04   NaN   NaN
3  David  7.42  3.52   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

**Explanation:**

***Step1:*** Set the `Name` column as index so we can deal with numeric values only.
**Step2:** `m.mask(m.le(0)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]` gives the first value which is greater than 0.
**Step3:** Then using `isin()` to return `True` wherever the value appears in each row.
**Step4:** `cumsum(axis=1).astype(bool)` makes all the remaining elements as True so we can filter only those values, other values becomes `NaN`.
Then use justify function from the linked post.