# How do I remove all the duplicates in each column respectively?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have multiple columns in a dataframe.

Some have duplicates, others are completely empty.

I need to delete the duplicates within each column.

```
dict_A = {'Firm_A': ['A', 'A', 'B','C'],'Firm_B': [], 'Firm_C': ['B', 'A', 'B','D'], 'Firm_D': ['C', 'C', 'A','D']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_A, orient = 'index')
df = df.T
df

  Firm_A Firm_B Firm_C  Firm_D
0   A     None    C       C
1   A     None    A       C
2   B     None    B       A
3   C     None    D       A
```

Desired Output:

```
  Firm_A Firm_B Firm_C  Firm_D
0   A     None    C       C
1   B     None    A       A
2   C     None    B       None
3  None   None    D       None
```

So far I have tried drop.duplicates().

I have around 3000 columns with each column having around 100 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using `duplicated`

```
df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,0)).apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull))
Out[542]: 
  Firm_A Firm_B Firm_C Firm_D
0      A   None      C      C
1      B    NaN      A      A
2      C    NaN      B    NaN
3    NaN    NaN      D    NaN
```

Also if you want to speed up check [justify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this with the wrong data structure.  If the entries in a data frame row are not related to one another, then a df is likely not an applicable data structure.  Instead, de-dup your dictionary values:

```
DictA = {k: list(set(v)) for k, v in DictA.items()}
```

After that, if you happen to have some strange application for data frame columns, you can build the df from there.

Comment: You may want to add sorted `{k: list(sorted(set(v),key=v.index)) for k, v in dict_A.items()}
`

Comment: Why add sorted?  OP's example assumes stability in the de-dup process, which I've ignored (left for the student) in my example.  `sorted` adds work to the instability, neh?

Comment: I think set will order the list . at least on my side can you check the output ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack` to convert `df` to `series`. Next, groupby on `level=1` and call `unique` to construct lists of unique values per column. Finally, construct a new `df` from `unique` and transpose

```
s = df.stack().groupby(level=1).unique()

Out[279]:
Firm_A       [A, B, C]
Firm_B          [None]
Firm_C    [C, A, B, D]
Firm_D          [C, A]
dtype: object


pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=df.columns).T.reindex(df.index)

Out[280]:
  Firm_A Firm_B Firm_C Firm_D
0      A   None      C      C
1      B   None      A      A
2      C   None      B   None
3   None   None      D   None
```