# How to move values over in each Pandas data frame row where np.nan are located?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H 
 0    0   2   3   5  NaN NaN NaN NaN
 1    2   7   9   1   2  NaN NaN NaN
 2    1   5   7   2   1   2   1  NaN
 3    6   1   3   2   1   1   5   5
 4    1   2   3   6  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

How do I move all of the numerical values to the end of each row and place the NANs before them? Such that I get a pandas data frame like this:

```
      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H 
 0   NaN NaN NaN NaN  0   2   3   5
 1   NaN NaN NaN  2   7   9   1   2  
 2   NaN  1   5   7   2   1   2   1 
 3    6   1   3   2   1   1   5   5
 4   NaN NaN NaN NaN  1   2   3   6
```

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180) answer from Divakar and use : `pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values,np.nan,side='right'),columns=df.columns)`

Answer (score 3):

One row solution:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x[x.isna()==True], x[x.isna()==False]], ignore_index=True), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best approach is to work row by row. Make a function to do the job and use `apply` or `transform` to use that function on each row.

```
def movenan(x):
    fl = len(x)
    nl = len(x.dropna())
    nanarr = np.empty(fl - nl)
    nanarr[:] = np.nan
    return pd.concat([pd.Series(nanarr), x.dropna()], ignore_index=True)

ddf = df.transform(movenan, axis=1)
ddf.columns = df.columns
```

Using your sample data, the resulting `ddf` is:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  2.0  3.0  5.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  7.0  9.0  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  1.0  5.0  7.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
3  6.0  1.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  5.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  6.0
```

The `movenan` function creates an array of `nan` of the required length, drops the `nan` from the row, and concatenates the two resulting Series.
`ignore_index=True` is required because you don't want to preserve data position in their columns (values are moved to different columns), but doing this the column names are lost and replaced by integers. The last line simply copies back the column names into the new dataframe.