# Remove NAs in each columns separatly and join them - Python

Tags: python, pandas

For example, if I have this data:

```
X1  X2  X3 
a   b   Na 
Na  Na  Na 
b   Na  a 
c   c   Na
```

The final result would be something like:

```
    X1  X2  X3 
    a   b   a
    b   c   Na
    c   Na  Na
```

I tried this funcion:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.unique(x)))
```

but I get:

```
    X1  X2  X3 
    a   b   Na 
    b   c   a 
    c   Na
```

How can I use the function but implementing ignore the NAs in pd.unique(x)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()))

print (df)
  X1   X2   X3
0  a    b    a
1  b    c  NaN
2  c  NaN  NaN
```

For improve performance is possible use a bit changed [justify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180) function by Divakar:

```
def justify(a, invalid_val=0, axis=1, side='left'):    
    """
    Justifies a 2D array

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. It could be 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
        It should be 'left' or 'right' for axis=1 and 'up' or 'down' for axis=0.

    """

    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        #change to notnull
        mask = pd.notnull(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    if (side=='up') | (side=='left'):
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
    #change dtype to object
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val, dtype=object)  
    if axis==1:
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
    return out
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, side='up', axis=0), 
                  columns=df.columns).dropna(how='all')
print (df)
  X1   X2   X3
0  a    b    a
1  b    c  NaN
2  c  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

IIUC here's a `NumPy` based approach:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.take_along_axis(df.values, df.isna().values.argsort(0), 0)
pd.DataFrame(a, columns=df.columns)

    X1   X2   X3
0    a    b    a
1    b    c  NaN
2    c  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

Double check your missing values are actual `np.nan`s, otherwise you can use:

```
df.replace('Na', float('nan'), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()).apply(pd.Series).T


    X1  X2  X3
0   a   b   a
1   b   c   NaN
2   c   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat):

```
print( pd.concat((df[c].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for c in df.columns), axis=1) )
```

Prints:

```
  X1   X2   X3
0  a    b    a
1  b    c  NaN
2  c  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add the function `.dropna()` to yours:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.unique(x.dropna())))
```

hope this helps