# Pivot dataframe by column (ID) duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, melt

I have a DataFrame with a column named 'ID' that has duplicate observations. Each 'ID' row has one or more 'Article' values columns. I want to transpose the whole dataframe grouping by 'ID' adding new columns at the same row of a unique 'ID'. Order is important

My DataFrame:

```
ID  Article     Article_2
1   Banana      NaN
2   Apple       NaN
1   Apple       Coconut
3   Tomatoe     Coconut
1   Pineapple   Tropical
2   Banana      Coconut
4   Apple       Coconut
5   Apple       Coconut
3   Apple       Pineapple
```

My code (by @Erfan):

```
dfn = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['Article', 'Article_2'])
dfn = dfn.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                      columns=dfn.groupby('ID')['value'].cumcount().add(1),
                      values='value',
                      aggfunc='first').add_prefix('Article_').rename_axis(None, axis='index')
```

Output:

```
        Article_1   Article_2   Article_3   Article_4   Article_5   Article_6
0001    Banana      Apple       Pineapple   NaN         Coconut     Tropical
0002    Apple       Banana      NaN         Coconut     NaN         NaN
0003    Tomatoe     Apple       Coconut     Pineapple   NaN         NaN
0004    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
0005    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

At first row, Article_4 is NaN and Article_5 and 6 have values. It should be Article_4 Coconut, Article_5 Tropical and Article_6 NaN.
At the second same, Article_3 is NaN and Article_4 is a valid value. It should be Article_3 valid and rest (4,5,6) NaNs

Needed output:

```
        Article_1   Article_2   Article_3   Article_4   Article_5   Article_6
0001    Banana      Apple       Pineapple   Coconut     Tropical    NaN     
0002    Apple       Banana      Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN
0003    Tomatoe     Apple       Coconut     Pineapple   NaN         NaN
0004    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
0005    Apple       Coconut     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) after `melt` for remove missing rows by `value` column:

```
dfn = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['Article', 'Article_2']).dropna(subset=['value'])

dfn = dfn.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                      columns=dfn.groupby('ID')['value'].cumcount().add(1),
                      values='value',
                      aggfunc='first').add_prefix('Article_').rename_axis(None, axis='index')

print (dfn)
  Article_1 Article_2  Article_3  Article_4 Article_5
1    Banana     Apple  Pineapple    Coconut  Tropical
2     Apple    Banana    Coconut        NaN       NaN
3   Tomatoe     Apple    Coconut  Pineapple       NaN
4     Apple   Coconut        NaN        NaN       NaN
5     Apple   Coconut        NaN        NaN       NaN
```

If need all columns use a bit modified `justify` function:

```
dfn = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['Article', 'Article_2'])

dfn = dfn.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                      columns=dfn.groupby('ID')['value'].cumcount().add(1),
                      values='value',
                      aggfunc='first').add_prefix('Article_').rename_axis(None, axis='index')
```

---

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/2901002
def justify(a, invalid_val=0, axis=1, side='left'):    
    """
    Justifies a 2D array

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. It could be 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
        It should be 'left' or 'right' for axis=1 and 'up' or 'down' for axis=0.

    """

    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = pd.notna(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    if (side=='up') | (side=='left'):
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val, dtype=object) 
    if axis==1:
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
    return out
```

---

```
dfn = pd.DataFrame(justify(dfn.values, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='left'),
                   index=dfn.index, columns=dfn.columns)
print (dfn)
  Article_1 Article_2  Article_3  Article_4 Article_5 Article_6
1    Banana     Apple  Pineapple    Coconut  Tropical       NaN
2     Apple    Banana    Coconut        NaN       NaN       NaN
3   Tomatoe     Apple    Coconut  Pineapple       NaN       NaN
4     Apple   Coconut        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
5     Apple   Coconut        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
```