# Sort arrangement of Pandas column values?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume, I have a Pandas DataFrame as following:

```
|    0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
|-----:|----:|----:|----:|
| 1115 | nan | "YE"| nan |
| 1590 | nan | "He"| "NO"|
```

How can I rearrange such a DataFrame consisting of over 100 columns and rows, that the `nan` values are shifted to the right side and the real values to the left side:

Desired output:

```
|    0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
|-----:|----:|----:|----:|
| 1115 | "YE"| nan | nan |
| 1590 | "HE"| "NO"| nan |
```

Note: this should also work for an arbitrary number of columns and rows.

Comment: Related to [the justify function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=df.T.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).T
      0    0     1    2
0  1115  "YE"   NaN  NaN
1  1590  "He"  "NO"  NaN
```