# How do I remove a specific value from a row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
   Column1 Column2 Column3
 0   1  NaN  NaN
 1   4  NaN  NaN
 2  NaN  3   NaN
 3  NaN  98  NaN
 4  NaN NaN  562
 5  NaN NaN  742
 .
 .
 .
```

How would I go about removing all of the unnecessary NaNs and make it look like this

```
   Column1 Column2 Column3
0    1   3   562
1    4   98  742
.
.
.
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Where does that data even come from, is there no way of fixing it beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.dropna().reset_index(drop=True).astype(int))
```

Just apply to each column a function, which drops *NaN* values in this column.
Due to presence of *NaN* values column are generally of *float* type,
but I attempt to cast them to *int*.

Note also that other solutions work only as long as each column contains
equal number of non-NaN values.

To check it, add the following row:

```
6  NaN   NaN   999
```

to your 6 initial rows, so that now *Column3* contains **3** non-Nan values,
whereas other columns - only **2**.

Solution by *yatu* drops this last row, whereas solution by *Quang*
results in *ValueError: arrays must all be same length*.

But my solution works OK also in this case, leaving trailing *NaN*
in "too short" columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can just `dropna`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().values)
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0      1.0      3.0    562.0
1      4.0     98.0    742.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/9698684) here from the linked post:

```
pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, side='up', axis=0), 
             columns=df.columns).dropna()

  Row1  Row2   Row3
0   1.0   3.0  562.0
1   4.0  98.0  742.0
```