# reformatting dataframe so every other value in series is used without nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

edit: in response to Jezrael misunderstanding what I am looking to do.

Using his example: What I am hoping to do is keep rb85 and rb87 values separate. I am trying to take my columns of values and create a new df which is half the rows# and has columns composed of either exclusively the odd or even index of the original. 
So rather than his example, I want to go from:

```
    rb85  rb87  rf85  rf87
0   7.0   NaN   3.0   NaN
1   NaN   5.0   NaN   4.0
2   9.0   NaN   9.0   NaN
3   NaN   5.0   NaN   5.0
4   2.0   NaN   2.0   NaN
5   NaN   4.0   NaN   4.0
```

to this:

```
   rb85  rb87  rf85  rf87
0   7.0   5.0   3.0   4.0 
1   9.0   5.0   9.0   5.0
2   2.0   4.0   2.0   4.0
```

How can I add every other value in a series and avoid nans? 
In my original data set I had two samples (rb85 and rb87) of data (shunt resistor or sr for short) taken sequentially ex: [sr85(1), sr87(1), sr85(2), sr87(2),...]

I am looking at how to take all rb85 (every even entry) and place it within its own series, and do the same for rb87 and both sample's output (rf85 and rf87).

[image: Original df]

[image: screen cap of code]

Comment: how large is your data set?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If possible, seelct each second column by indexing by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), last remove only missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and `how='all'` parameter:

```
df.iloc[:, 1::2] = df.iloc[:, 1::2].shift(-1)
df = df.dropna(how='all')
print (df)
   rb85  rb87  rf85  rf87
0   7.0   5.0   3.0   4.0
2   9.0   5.0   9.0   5.0
4   2.0   4.0   2.0   4.0
```

Another solution with [`justify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/2901002) function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(justify(df.values, invalid_val=np.nan, side='up', axis=0), 
                  columns=df.columns).dropna(how='all')
print (df)
   rb85  rb87  rf85  rf87
0   7.0   5.0   3.0   4.0
1   9.0   5.0   9.0   5.0
2   2.0   4.0   2.0   4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm sorry that I wasn't clear. What I am hoping to do is keep rb85 and rb87 values separate. I am trying to take my columns of values and create a new df which is half the rows# and has columns composed of either exclusively the odd or even index of the original. I've updated my original question to reflect this better.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas on how this can be achieved depending on size of your data + how dynamic it needs to be. But just to answer your question you can shift back every second column by 1 row and then drop rows that are nan:

```
for col in df.columns[1::2]:
    df[col] = df[col].shift(-1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

output

```
    rb85    rb87    rf85    rf87
0   7.0     5.0     3.0     4.0
2   9.0     5.0     9.0     5.0
4   2.0     4.0     2.0     4.0
```

you can then reset index if needed

`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

```
    rb85    rb87    rf85    rf87
0   7.0     5.0     3.0     4.0
1   9.0     5.0     9.0     5.0
2   2.0     4.0     2.0     4.0
```