# Fill NaN values from previous column with data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas, and I am trying to take data from the same row and different columns and fill NaN values in my data. How would I do this in pandas?

For example,

```
      1     2   3     4     5   6   7  8  9  10  11    12    13  14    15    16
83  27.0  29.0 NaN  29.0  30.0 NaN NaN  15.0 16.0  17.0 NaN  28.0  30.0 NaN  28.0  18.0
```

The goal is for the data to look like this:

```
      1     2   3     4     5   6   7  ...    10  11    12    13  14    15    16
83  NaN  NaN NaN  27.0  29.0 29.0 30.0  ...  15.0 16.0  17.0  28.0 30.0  28.0  18.0
```

The goal is to be able to take the mean of the last five columns that have data. If there are not >= 5 data-filled cells, then take the average of however many cells there are.

Comment: You have five nans in the first "row" and three in the second, which makes it a bit puzzling.

Comment: That's unfortunately the best way I could type it. The dataframe is quite large, so it only shows an abridged version of each row.

Comment: `If there are not >= 5 data-filled cells, then take the average of however many cells there are. ` Can you add some data to question with this? also what is `8,9` column with expected output? It seems data are gone from this columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `justify` for improve performance with filter all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df)
   name     1     2   3     4     5   6   7     8     9    10  11    12    13  \
80  bob  27.0  29.0 NaN  29.0  30.0 NaN NaN  15.0  16.0  17.0 NaN  28.0  30.0   

    14    15    16  
80 NaN  28.0  18.0  


df.iloc[:, 1:] = justify(df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy(), invalid_val=np.nan,  side='right')
print (df)
   name   1   2   3   4   5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13  \
80  bob NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  27.0  29.0  29.0  30.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  28.0   

      14    15    16  
80  30.0  28.0  18.0
```

Function:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/2901002
def justify(a, invalid_val=0, axis=1, side='left'):    
    """
    Justifies a 2D array

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. It could be 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
        It should be 'left' or 'right' for axis=1 and 'up' or 'down' for axis=0.

    """

    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    if (side=='up') | (side=='left'):
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val) 
    if axis==1:
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
    return out
```

**Performance**:

```
#100 rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 100, ignore_index=True)

#41 times slowier
In [39]: %timeit df.loc[:,df.columns[1:]] =  df.loc[:,df.columns[1:]].apply(fun, axis=1)
145 ms ± 23.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


In [41]: %timeit df.iloc[:, 1:] = justify(df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy(), invalid_val=np.nan,  side='right')
3.54 ms ± 236 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
#1000 rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

#198 times slowier
In [43]: %timeit df.loc[:,df.columns[1:]] =  df.loc[:,df.columns[1:]].apply(fun, axis=1)
1.13 s ± 37.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [45]: %timeit df.iloc[:, 1:] = justify(df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy(), invalid_val=np.nan,  side='right')
5.7 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to move all `NaN` to the first columns I would define a function that takes all `NaN` and places them first and leave the rest as it is:

```
def fun(row):
    index_order = row.index[row.isnull()].append(row.index[~row.isnull()])
    row.iloc[:] = row[index_order].values
    return row

df_fix = df.loc[:,df.columns[1:]].apply(fun, axis=1)
```

If you need to overwrite the results in the same dataframe then:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns[1:]] = df_fix.copy()
```

Comment: This is a huge step in the right direction! Thank you. There is a name column that is at column[0], so how would I work around that, as the names are integral to the relational aspect of the dataframe.

Comment: just call the `fun` of the answer on row[1:], and prepend the first element to the result.

Comment: Thanks @IgorRivin, you can also apply the function to all columns but the first one (column[0]), check the edit.

Comment: @jcaliz - hmmm, I think better is not using loops in pandas, because slow, check timings in my answer.

Comment: Yeah @jezrael I agree that loops are not good for pandas, this was just an easy quick and simple to explain solution.