# Python Pandas Delete empty cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to delete empty cells with pandas. I wanna delete only empty cells but I have no idea how to do that.

ex

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | price | 10 |  |  | quantity | 5 |  |  |
| 2 | pineapple | price | 12 | condition | good |  |  | quantity | 4 |

what I want

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | price | 10 | quantity | 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | pineapple | price | 12 | condition | good | quantity | 4 |  |  |

I need all values without empty cells. So I don't want to delete whole row or column. I wanna delete empty cell and pull the values ​​in the back.

Real Data
[EXCEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgbnS.jpg)

Comment: Please share a dataframe - or part of the file you import into pandas using load_csv.  this might be as easy as provide some more parameters on load. post a [mre] as well so we see how your df is created.

Comment: I shared as image file. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062157/move-non-empty-cells-to-the-left-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with this

[Removing nan from pandas dataframe and reshaping dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569994/removing-nan-from-pandas-dataframe-and-reshaping-dataframe)

Keypoint : Change Invalid_val with len of value strings