# justify data from right to left

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, series

I have a dataset of rows containing varying lengths of integer values in a series. I want to separate the series so each integer has its own column but align these values along the right-most column. I want the dataframe to resenble upper triangle of a matrix.

Currently I have a dataset like:

```
    variable    value
0   0   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
1   1   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2   2   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
3   3   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
4   4   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
5   5   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
6   6   [1, 2, 3, 4]
7   7   [1, 2, 3]
8   8   [1, 2]
9   9   [1]
```

I apply this function

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for x in df2.value])
df.columns = ['{}'.format(x+1) for x in df.columns]
```

and I get this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 0.0
1   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 NaN
2   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 NaN NaN
3   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 NaN NaN NaN
4   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   1.0 2.0 3.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   1.0 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

But what i want is this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 0.0
1   NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 
2   NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 
3   NaN NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 
6   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
7   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 
8   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 
9   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0
```

Comment: Here's very good answer by divakar in numpy [`justify numpy array`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/12416453)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to calculate the `max` length of the list in the column `value` i.e `lmax` then using list comprehension `pad` each of the list based on `lmax`:

```
lmax = df['value'].str.len().max()
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * (lmax - len(s)) + s
                    for s in df['value']], columns=range(1, lmax + 1))
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  10
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0   0
1  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0   9
2  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0   8
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0   7
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0   6
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   5
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0   4
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0   3
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0   2
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1
```

Comment: Nice answer, Check this [answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/12416453)+1

Comment: Hey thank you for your solution, I am getting an error when I try to implement it saying "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (10,)" I am unsure what this means and how to fix this.

Comment: Because my arrays were numpy arrays, we modified the code such as: `lmax = df['value'].str.len().max()
df1 = pd.DataFrame([np.hstack([[np.nan] * (lmax - len(s)), s]) for s in df['value']], columns=range(1, lmax + 1))`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `np.pad`, but need to cast the dtype of each array into `float` first in order to fill with `nan`:

```
s = pd.DataFrame([np.pad(np.array(a).astype(float), (10 - len(a), 0), mode="constant",
                         constant_values=np.NaN) for a in df["value"]])
print (s)

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
1  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0   9.0
2  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0   8.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0   7.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0   6.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0   5.0
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0   4.0
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0   3.0
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0   2.0
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0
```

Comment: I also thought of using `np.pad`, but i guess using `np.pad` adds a extra overhead here ;). What's your opinion?

Comment: Yeah it was a lot of work to get the expected output using `np.pad`. I think yours is more straight forward :)

Comment: yeah, that 's what i though so when i was experimenting with `np.pad` here ;). BTW good answer +1.