# How to efficiently 'move up' Values into NaN positions in 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, lstm, data-manipulation

I have a dataset of nested lists, all of the same length (bigger than 120). I only need the latest 120 **valid** values.
(so like rowwise moving up the NaN Values to the end and then selecting the last 120 **is one way to do it**).

How to do that efficiently? (because I got millions of these Samples)

```
[# Samples list
 [ # Sample 1
  [ 89.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787      NaN 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 23.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  ... 
  [ 23.319787 1.329743 45.234670 ... 52.329743  0.32721 2.319787 ] 
  [ 89.319787      NaN 99.234670 ...       NaN      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787 1.329743       NaN ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743       NaN ... 52.329743      NaN 2.319787 ] 
                                                                  ],
 [ # Sample 2
  [ 89.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787      NaN 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 23.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  ... 
  [ 23.319787 1.329743 45.234670 ... 52.329743  0.32721 2.319787 ] 
  [ 89.319787      NaN 99.234670 ...       NaN      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787 1.329743       NaN ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787      NaN       NaN ... 52.329743      NaN 2.319787 ] 
                                                                  ],
[...],
[...],
[...],

 [ # Sample n
  [ 89.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [       NaN 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787      NaN 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 23.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  ... 
  [ 23.319787 1.329743 45.234670 ... 52.329743  0.32721 2.319787 ] 
  [ 89.319787      NaN 99.234670 ...       NaN      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787 1.329743       NaN ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743       NaN ... 52.329743      NaN 2.319787 ] 
                                                                  ]
]
```

expected outcome: (this is only one way it could be done, because I only need the latest 120 valid values in each vertical "column", while each vertical "column" necessarily always has more than 120 valid values)
Note: since the examples only show 9 rows per sample and the vertical column with the least valid elements has 6 non-NaN elements, one can use 6 instead of 120 valids.

```
[# Samples list
 [ # Sample 1
  [ 89.319787      NaN       NaN ...       NaN      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787      NaN       NaN ... 52.329743      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  ... 
  [ 23.319787 1.329743 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 89.319787 1.329743 23.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 45.234670 ... 52.329743  0.32721 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
                                                                  ],
 [ # Sample 2
  [ 89.319787      NaN       NaN ...       NaN      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787      NaN       NaN ... 52.329743      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787      NaN 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  ... 
  [ 23.319787 1.329743 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 89.319787 1.329743 23.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 45.234670 ... 52.329743  0.32721 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
                                                                  ], 
[...],
[...],
[...],

 [ # Sample n
  [       NaN      NaN       NaN ...       NaN      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787      NaN       NaN ... 52.329743      NaN 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787      NaN 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  ... 
  [ 23.319787 1.329743 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 89.319787 1.329743 23.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
  [ 84.319787 1.329743 45.234670 ... 52.329743  0.32721 2.319787 ] 
  [ 12.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743    0.319 2.319787 ] 
  [ 33.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
                                                                  ],
]
```

Sample Data:

```
samples = [[
[89.319787,1.329743,99.234670,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787],
[12.319787,np.nan,33.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[33.319787,1.329743,23.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[23.319787,1.329743,45.234670,52.329743,0.32721,2.319787],
[89.319787,np.nan,99.234670,np.nan,np.nan,2.319787],
[84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787],
[12.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[33.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,np.nan,2.319787]
],
[
[89.319787,1.329743,99.234670,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787],
[12.319787,np.nan,33.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[33.319787,1.329743,23.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[23.319787,1.329743,45.234670,52.329743,0.32721,2.319787],
[89.319787,np.nan,99.234670,np.nan,np.nan,2.319787],
[84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787],
[12.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[33.319787,np.nan,np.nan,52.329743,np.nan,2.319787]
],
[
[89.319787,1.329743,99.234670,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[np.nan,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787],
[12.319787,np.nan,33.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[33.319787,1.329743,23.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[23.319787,1.329743,45.234670,52.329743,0.32721,2.319787],
[89.319787,np.nan,99.234670,np.nan,np.nan,2.319787],
[84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787],
[12.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787],
[33.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,np.nan,2.319787]]]
```

Comment: This should help - [`Python: Justifying NumPy array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array).

Comment: looks interesting, is there a way to do this in a vectorized way ? (all samples at the 'same' time), (because otherwise iteration over millions of samples)