# Why doesnt this justify function work properly? (justifys right instead of down)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, justify

The following [justify function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/9698684) should move the data fown in the rows, if there is a NaN value (so that the NaN will be at the top.
But somehow the "down" option does the same as the "right".
How to fix?

Here is the reproducable data (its a 3d array):

```
import numpy as np
def justify(a, invalid_val=0, axis=1, side='left'):    
    """  Justifies a 2D array 
    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. It could be 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
        It should be 'left' or 'right' for axis=1 and 'up' or 'down' for axis=0. 
    """ 
    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    if (side=='up') | (side=='left'):
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val) 
    if axis==1:
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
    return out

a = np.asarray([
 np.asarray([np.asarray([ 1.21643707,  0.9280912,   5.20711915]),
  np.asarray([-2.01148217,  2.72869681,  2.54161257]),
  np.asarray([ 0.49170286,  0.72304396,  1.56706948]),
  np.asarray([-0.77553082,  2.74300372,  0.10107189]),
  np.asarray([ 2.54368976,  0.53107898,  0.09351025]),
  np.asarray([ 1.03176737, -0.54742843,      np.nan])])])


b = justify(a, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='down')
print(a) 
print(b)
```

real output:

```
#a
[[[ 1.21643707  0.9280912   5.20711915]
  [-2.01148217  2.72869681  2.54161257]
  [ 0.49170286  0.72304396  1.56706948]
  [-0.77553082  2.74300372  0.10107189]
  [ 2.54368976  0.53107898  0.09351025]
  [ 1.03176737 -0.54742843         nan]]]
_
#b
[[[ 1.21643707  0.9280912          nan]
  [ 5.20711915 -2.01148217  2.72869681]
  [ 2.54161257  0.49170286  0.72304396]
  [ 1.56706948 -0.77553082  2.74300372]
  [ 0.10107189  2.54368976  0.53107898]
  [ 0.09351025  1.03176737 -0.54742843]]]
```

actually expected output:

```
#a
[[[ 1.21643707  0.9280912   5.20711915]
  [-2.01148217  2.72869681  2.54161257]
  [ 0.49170286  0.72304396  1.56706948]
  [-0.77553082  2.74300372  0.10107189]
  [ 2.54368976  0.53107898  0.09351025]
  [ 1.03176737 -0.54742843         nan]]]
_
# expected b
[[[ 1.21643707  0.9280912          nan]
  [-2.01148217  2.72869681  5.20711915]
  [ 0.49170286  0.72304396  2.54161257]
  [-0.77553082  2.74300372  1.56706948]
  [ 2.54368976  0.53107898  0.10107189]
  [ 1.03176737 -0.54742843  0.09351025]]]
```

So the 'real' output is the same as the input side="right". Why is that happening, or better is there a way to fix it?

EDIT: unconsciously wrote "my", i didnt mean its mine, sry. (credit: Divakar)

EDIT2: more detailled sample (3d):

```
# in reality were dealing with about 1million samples (==2d matrices) of 50 'columns' and 10.000 'rows'

samples = np.asarray([np.asarray([
np.asarray([89.319787,1.329743,99.234670,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787]),
np.asarray([12.319787,np.nan,33.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([33.319787,1.329743,23.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([23.319787,1.329743,45.234670,52.329743,0.32721,2.319787]),
np.asarray([89.319787,np.nan,99.234670,np.nan,np.nan,2.319787]),
np.asarray([84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787]),
np.asarray([12.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([33.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,np.nan,2.319787])
]),
np.asarray([
np.asarray([89.319787,1.329743,99.234670,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787]),
np.asarray([12.319787,np.nan,33.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([33.319787,1.329743,23.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([23.319787,1.329743,45.234670,52.329743,0.32721,2.319787]),
np.asarray([89.319787,np.nan,99.234670,np.nan,np.nan,2.319787]),
np.asarray([84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787]),
np.asarray([12.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([33.319787,np.nan,np.nan,52.329743,np.nan,2.319787])
]),
np.asarray([
np.asarray([89.319787,1.329743,99.234670,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([np.nan,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787]),
np.asarray([12.319787,np.nan,33.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([33.319787,1.329743,23.329743,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([23.319787,1.329743,45.234670,52.329743,0.32721,2.319787]),
np.asarray([89.319787,np.nan,99.234670,np.nan,np.nan,2.319787]),
np.asarray([84.319787,1.329743,49.329743,52.329743,0.319,2.319787]),
np.asarray([12.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,0.319787,2.319787]),
np.asarray([33.319787,1.329743,np.nan,52.329743,np.nan,2.319787])])])
```

Comment: It's meant for 2D array. Hence, use `justify(a[0], invalid_val=np.nan, axis=0, side='down')`.

Comment: @ALollz nope , I think that is Divakar's function ~

Comment: @BEN_YO youre right, edited post thx. isnt there a way to do it for 3d arrays?

Comment: @La-Li-Lu-Le-Lo Would your 3D array have only one element along the first axis like in the posted sample? If so, then simply `justify(a[0], invalid_val=np.nan, axis=0, side='down')` works. If not, we need to get a generic one.

Comment: @Divakar unfortunately multiple ones. I can post another the sample too. EDIT: added  a reproducable sample

Comment: @La-Li-Lu-Le-Lo With the edited Q&A answer post's func : `justify_generic(a, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side='end')`.

Comment: renamed to `justify_nd`.

Comment: thank you very much, the generic function seems to work well^^. currently trying how time efficient it is on my real data.