# Group Pandas rows by ID and forward fill them to the right retaining NaN when it appears on all the rows with the same ID

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate, nan

I have a Pandas DataFrame that I need to:

- group by the ID column (not in index)
- forward fill rows to the right with the previous value (multiple columns) only if it's not a NaN (`np.nan`)

For each ID categorical value and each metric column (see the `aX` columns in the examples below) there is only value (the others when having multiple rows are NaN - `np.nan`).

Take this as an example:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                           

In [2]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                          

In [3]: my_df = pd.DataFrame([ 
   ...:     {"id": 1, "a1": 100.0, "a2": np.nan, "a3": np.nan, "a4": 90.0}, 
   ...:     {"id": 1, "a1": np.nan, "a2": np.nan, "a3": 80.0, "a4": np.nan}, 
   ...:     {"id": 20, "a1": np.nan, "a2": np.nan, "a3": 100.0, "a4": np.nan}, 
   ...:     {"id": 20, "a1": np.nan, "a2": np.nan, "a3": np.nan, "a4": 30.0}, 
   ...: ])                                                                                                                           

In [4]: my_df.head(len(my_df))                                                                                                       
Out[4]: 
   id     a1  a2     a3    a4
0   1  100.0 NaN    NaN  90.0
1   1    NaN NaN   80.0   NaN
2  20    NaN NaN  100.0   NaN
3  20    NaN NaN    NaN  30.0
```

I have many more columns like `a1` to `a4`.

I would like to:

- pretend `np.nan` is zero `0.0` when on the same column and different row (with same ID) there is a number so I can sum them together like with `groupby` and subsequent aggregation functions
- forward fill to the right on the same unique row (by ID) only if somewhere on a previous column to the left there was a number

So basically in the example this means that:

- for ID `1` `"a2"=100.0`
- for ID `2` `"a1"` and `"a2"` are both `np.nan`

See here:

```py
In [5]: wanted_df = pd.DataFrame([ 
   ...:     {"id": 1, "a1": 100.0, "a2": 100.0, "a3": 80.0, "a4": 90.0}, 
   ...:     {"id": 20, "a1": np.nan, "a2": np.nan, "a3": 100.0, "a4": 30.0}, 
   ...: ])                                                                                                                           

In [6]: wanted_df.head(len(wanted_df))                                                                                               
Out[6]: 
   id     a1     a2     a3    a4
0   1  100.0  100.0   80.0  90.0
1  20    NaN    NaN  100.0  30.0

In [7]:
```

The forward filling to the right should apply to multiple columns on the same row,
not only for the closest row to the right.

When I use `my_df.interpolate(method='pad', axis=1,limit=None,limit_direction='forward',limit_area=None,downcast=None,)` then I still get multiple rows for the same ID.

When I use `my_df.groupby("id").sum()` then I see `0.0` everywhere rather than retaining the NaN values in those scenarios defined above.

When I use `my_df.groupby("id").apply(np.sum)` the ID columns is summed as well, so this is wrong as it should be retained.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use `min_count=1` to `sum`:

```
df = my_df.groupby("id").sum(min_count=1)
print (df)
       a1  a2     a3    a4
id                        
1   100.0 NaN   80.0  90.0
20    NaN NaN  100.0  30.0
```

Or if need first non missing value is possible use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = my_df.groupby("id").first()
print (df)
       a1  a2     a3    a4
id                        
1   100.0 NaN   80.0  90.0
20    NaN NaN  100.0  30.0
```

---

More problematic is if multiple non missing values per groups and need all of them:

```
#added 20 to a1
my_df = pd.DataFrame([ 
     {"id": 1, "a1": 100.0, "a2": np.nan, "a3": np.nan, "a4": 90.0}, 
      {"id": 1, "a1": 20, "a2": np.nan, "a3": 80.0, "a4": np.nan}, 
      {"id": 20, "a1": np.nan, "a2": np.nan, "a3": 100.0, "a4": np.nan}, 
     {"id": 20, "a1": np.nan, "a2": np.nan, "a3": np.nan, "a4": 30.0}, 
 ])   
print (my_df)              
   id     a1  a2     a3    a4
0   1  100.0 NaN    NaN  90.0
1   1   20.0 NaN   80.0   NaN
2  20    NaN NaN  100.0   NaN
3  20    NaN NaN    NaN  30.0
```

---

```
def f(x):
    return x.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()))

df1 = (my_df.set_index('id')
            .groupby("id")
            .apply(f)
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
            .reset_index())
print (df1)

   id     a1  a2     a3    a4
0   1  100.0 NaN   80.0  90.0
1   1   20.0 NaN    NaN   NaN
2  20    NaN NaN  100.0  30.0
```

First and second solution working differently:

```
df2 = my_df.groupby("id").sum(min_count=1)
print (df2)
       a1  a2     a3    a4
id                        
1   120.0 NaN   80.0  90.0
20    NaN NaN  100.0  30.0

df3 = my_df.groupby("id").first()
print (df3)
       a1  a2     a3    a4
id                        
1   100.0 NaN   80.0  90.0
20    NaN NaN  100.0  30.0
```

If same type of values, here numbers is possible also use:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/2901002
def justify(a, invalid_val=0, axis=1, side='left'):    
    """
    Justifies a 2D array

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. It could be 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
        It should be 'left' or 'right' for axis=1 and 'up' or 'down' for axis=0.

    """

    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    if (side=='up') | (side=='left'):
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val) 
    if axis==1:
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        out.T[justified_mask.T] = a.T[mask.T]
    return out
```

---

```
f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(justify(x.to_numpy(), 
                                   invalid_val=np.nan, 
                                   axis=0, 
                                   side='up'), columns=my_df.columns.drop('id'))
                .dropna(how='all')
df1 = (my_df.set_index('id')
            .groupby("id")
            .apply(f)
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
            .reset_index())
print (df1)
   id     a1  a2     a3    a4
0   1  100.0 NaN   80.0  90.0
1   1   20.0 NaN    NaN   NaN
2  20    NaN NaN  100.0  30.0
```

Comment: Yes that `.sum(min_count=1)` works quite good. However I need to forward fill to the right that `100.0` in `a1` for ID=1, how do I do that even when multiple columns to the right of `a1` are `np.nan`? Also: for each column `aX` there is only 1 value for a given ID - so the scenario where `a1` is both `100.0` and `20.0` for ID=1 is not the one I have. Thanks

Comment: @TPPZ Not sure if understand, do you need `df = my_df.groupby("id").sum(min_count=1).ffill(axis=1)`?