`pandas` rolling sum with a maximum number of valid observations in a window
I am looking for help to speed up a rolling calculation in pandas which would compute a rolling average with a predefined maximum number of most recent observations. Here is code to generate an example frame and the frame itself:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tmp = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [11.1]*3 + [12.1]*3 + [13.1]*3  + [14.1]*3 + [15.1]*3 + [16.1]*3 + [17.1]*3 + [18.1]*3,
        ['A', 'B', 'C']*8,
        [np.nan]*6 + [1, 1, 1] + [2, 2, 2] + [3, 3, 3] + [np.nan]*9
    ],
    index=['Date', 'Name', 'Val']
)
tmp = tmp.T.pivot(index='Date', columns='Name', values='Val')

Name    A    B    C
Date               
11.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
12.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
13.1    1    1    1
14.1    2    2    2
15.1    3    3    3
16.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
17.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
18.1  NaN  NaN  NaN

I would like to obtain this result:
Name    A    B    C
Date               
11.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
12.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
13.1  1.0  1.0  1.0
14.1  1.5  1.5  1.5
15.1  2.5  2.5  2.5
16.1  2.5  2.5  2.5
17.1  3.0  3.0  3.0
18.1  NaN  NaN  NaN

Attempted Solution
I tried the following code and it works, but its performance is very bad for data sets that I am stuck with in practice.
tmp.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x[~np.isnan(x)][-2:].mean(), raw=True)

Calculation above applied to a 3k x 50k frame takes about 20 minutes... Maybe there is a more elegant and faster way to obtain the same result? Maybe using a combination of multiple rolling computation results or something with groupby?
Versions
Python - 3.9.13, pandas - 2.0.3 and numpy - 1.25.2

One idea is use numba for faster count output in Rolling.apply by parameter engine='numba':
(tmp.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)
    .apply(lambda x: x[~np.isnan(x)][-2:].mean(), engine='numba', raw=True))

Test performance:
tmp = pd.concat([tmp] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [88]: %timeit tmp.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x[~np.isnan(x)][-2:].mean(),engine='numba', raw=True)
901 ms ± 6.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [89]: %timeit tmp.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x[~np.isnan(x)][-2:].mean(), raw=True)
13 s ± 181 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Numpy approach:
You can convert DataFrame to 3d array with append first NaNs values, then shift non NaNs and get means:
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/2901002
def justify_nd(a, invalid_val, axis, side):    
    """
    Justify ndarray for the valid elements (that are not invalid_val).

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    invalid_val : scalar
        invalid value
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. Must be 'front' or 'end'.
        So, with 'front', valid elements are pushed to the front and
        with 'end' valid elements are pushed to the end along specified axis.
    """
    
    pushax = lambda a: np.moveaxis(a, axis, -1)
    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    
    if side=='front':
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
            
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val)
    if (axis==-1) or (axis==a.ndim-1):
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        pushax(out)[pushax(justified_mask)] = pushax(a)[pushax(mask)]
    return out


from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

window_size = 3
N = 2

a = tmp.astype(float).to_numpy()
arr = np.vstack([np.full((window_size-1,a.shape[1]), np.nan),a])

out = np.nanmean(justify_nd(swv(arr, window_size, axis=0), 
                            invalid_val=np.nan, axis=2, side='end')[:, :, -N:], 
                 axis=2)

print (out)
[[nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan]
 [1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.5 1.5 1.5]
 [2.5 2.5 2.5]
 [2.5 2.5 2.5]
 [3.  3.  3. ]
 [nan nan nan]]


df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=tmp.index, columns=tmp.columns)
print (df)
Name    A    B    C
Date               
11.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
12.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
13.1  1.0  1.0  1.0
14.1  1.5  1.5  1.5
15.1  2.5  2.5  2.5
16.1  2.5  2.5  2.5
17.1  3.0  3.0  3.0
18.1  NaN  NaN  NaN

Performance:
tmp = pd.concat([tmp] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


In [99]: %%timeit
    ...: a = tmp.astype(float).to_numpy()
    ...: arr = np.vstack([np.full((window_size-1,a.shape[1]), np.nan),a])
    ...: 
    ...: out = np.nanmean(justify_nd(swv(arr, window_size, axis=0), 
    ...:                             invalid_val=np.nan, 
                                     axis=2, side='end')[:, :, -N:], axis=2)
    ...: 
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=tmp.index, columns=tmp.columns)
    ...: 

338 ms ± 4.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


Thank you for the good suggestion and this could be the way to go in most cases. Unfortunately, numba will not work for me because our environment has issues with it.

Thank you for numpy option too. It worked for me, but I started hitting memory limits very quickly. For most users, these two options are probably the way to go.
