# Create mask by first positions only

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, where-clause, mask

I have array:

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  4,  1, 35,  0, 10],
              [ 0,  0,  5,  4,  0,  4],
              [ 1,  2,  5,  4,  0,  4]])
```

I need select only from first consecutive `0` in each row:

```
[[  True   False  False  False  False  False]
 [  True   False  False  False  False  False]
 [  True   True   False  False  False  False]
 [  False  False  False  False  False  False]]
```

I try:

```
a[np.arange(len(a)), a.argmax(1): np.arange(len(a)), [0,0,0]] = True
```

But this is wrong.

Comment: @BradSolomon - yes, exactly. First consecutives.

Comment: Might be helpful: [Finding the consecutive zeros in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885092/finding-the-consecutive-zeros-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: I am looking for solution long time, but no sucess :(

Comment: Should the first zeros always start from the beginning or it could be in the middle of the row? or how about `2,4,0,0,4,5`? Should zeros be selected?

Comment: @Psidom - good question. I think not always should starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.cumsum`.

Assumption: you are looking for zeros only at the start of each row.

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  4,  1, 35,  0, 10],
              [ 0,  0,  5,  4,  0,  4]])

a.cumsum(axis=1) == 0
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Basis: holds `True` for as long as the cumulative sum is 0 along each row.

Error-prone: an array with negative ints would cause this to fail.  I.e. for `[-1, 1]`, this would evaluate to `True` at position 1.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [`np.minimum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) with the condition testing `a == 0`(over the rows); Since non zero gives `False`, so elements come after the first non zero will be set to `False` due to the accumulated minimum:

```
np.minimum.accumulate(a == 0, axis=1)
#array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
#       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
#       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
#       [False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with [`argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) + [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(a==0).argmin(1)[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1])
```

**Explanation with a sample step-by-step run**

1) Input array :

```
In [207]: a
Out[207]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  4,  1, 35,  0, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  4,  0,  4],
       [ 1,  2,  5,  4,  0,  4]])
```

2) Mask of zeros

```
In [208]: (a==0)
Out[208]: 
array([[ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

3) Get the indices where the False occurs signalling the end of first True island for each row. Thus, for any row where there is no zero or if the first element is  non-zero would result in argmin output as `0`. Thus, our next task would be to use `broadcasting` to create a mask that starts as True from first row and stops being True at those `argmin` indices. This would be one with `broadcasted-comparison` against a range array extending covering all columns.

```
In [209]: (a==0).argmin(1)
Out[209]: array([1, 1, 2, 0])

In [210]: (a==0).argmin(1)[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1])
Out[210]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

**Timings**

```
In [196]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(5000,5000))

In [197]: %timeit a.cumsum(axis=1) == 0 #@Brad Solomon
     ...: %timeit np.minimum.accumulate(a == 0, axis=1) #@Psidom
     ...: %timeit (a==0).argmin(1)[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1])
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 69 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 64.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 32.8 ms per loop
```